# Reference to the label of a figure brings up subsection lable

Tags: graphics

In Chapter 7 of my document which begins

```
\documentclass[pagesize=auto,bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrbook}
```

I include a figure (the first in chapter 7) using the code

```
\begin{figure}[h]

\label{fig:Z1}

\centering

\includegraphics*[width=0.8\textwidth]{images/Z.eps}

\caption{Probability of membership in Cluster 1}

\end{figure}
```

Figure `\ref{fig:Z1}` contains a plot of the first column of \verb|Z|.

Now the figure is captioned as Figure 7.1, as I would expect. However in the text following \end{figure} the reference `\ref{fig:Z1}` gives rise to 7.2.4, which is the number of the subsection in which the figure occurs.
What is going on?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: In `figure` and `table` environments, the `\label` directive must come *after*, not before, the `\caption` directive in order for LaTeX to be able to make the correct association between the label and the object (a `figure` or `table`) that's to be cross-referenced elsewhere in the document via `\ref` and similar commands.

Comment: For more information about how LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` system works, please see the query [Understanding how references and labels work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5001)