# Why referencing within xsim exercise/solution environment is not working?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, xsim

In the text of a solution, I would like to make a reference to a figure which is inside the solution environment as well, but it is not working. The code is as simple as:

```
\begin{solution}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{sample.jpg}
  \label{fig}
\end{figure}
As you can see in figure (\ref{fig})...
\end{solution}
```

And I always get a (??) in the output. Why is the referencing failing?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: You don't have a `\caption` *before* the `\label` *within* the `figure` environment.

Comment: See [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764)