# Which commands were executed by latexmk

Tags: latexmk

Recently I've discovered `latexmk` if I understand correct then it can replace several commands needed to compile latex just with one command. Is it possible to show which commands were executed when I issue e.g. `latexmk -pdf thesis.tex`? Or even better is it possible to run `latexmk` in some 'no action mode' to just print what commands should be issued to compile latex manually? I do not guess that latest is possible because during compilation are generated '*.aux', '*.bbl' files etc. which are read again and again as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121383/how-does-the-latex-compile-chain-work-exactly) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53235/why-does-latex-bibtex-need-three-passes-to-clear-up-all-warnings). So I guess some compilation must took place before we know if compilation is needed in next step or nor, but I will rather ask. Thanks

PS: I'm wondering of exact sequence of commands that were executed e.g.:

```
pdflatex thesis.tex
pdflatex thesis.tex
pdflatex thesis.tex
```

or

```
pdflatex thesis.tex
bibtex thesis.tex
pdflatex thesis.tex
pdflatex thesis.tex
```

Comment: At least on Linux, `latexmk` is actually (a symbolic link to) a long perl script (being long due to documentation and comments) but it does basically nothing more than to call the regular commands such as `latex`, `pdflatex` etc.

Comment: I know that it is basically calling regular commands but I'm wondering which commands are called for particular project. AFAIK `latexmk` somehow determine which commands to call to optimize compilation process. Or am I wrong and same set of commands are called every time I run `latexmk` regardless of if BibTeX, glossaries etc. is used or nor?

Comment: You can work out from the terminal output which commands `latexmk` ran on any particular call...

Comment: @Seamus is this correct approach: `latexmk -pdf thesis.tex 2>&1 | grep '^Running'`

Comment: In case you  don't want to dig through the terminal output, run `latexmk -time  -pdf thesis.tex`. This is intended to get timing information, but as a side effect it summarises all the steps at the end of the output.

Comment: I think @samcarter has a better solution.

Answer (score 6):

`latexmk` already provides the informations which of its rules it currently runs during it's terminal output. But in case you don't want to dig through the terminal output, run `latexmk -time -pdf thesis.tex`. This is originally intended to get timing information, but as a side effect it summarises all the steps at the end of the output.

```
'pdflatex  -recorder  "Thesis.tex"': time = 10.21
'biber  "Thesis"': time = 11.21
'pdflatex  -recorder  "Thesis.tex"': time = 11.52
'pdflatex  -recorder  "Thesis.tex"': time = 11.45
'pdflatex  -recorder  "Thesis.tex"': time = 11.48
Accumulated processing time = 57.02
```

Answer (score 3):

`latexmk --commands` provides the following list:

```
   To run latex, I use "latex %O %S"
   To run pdflatex, I use "pdflatex %O %S"
   To run biber, I use "biber %O %B"
   To run bibtex, I use "bibtex %O %B"
   To run makeindex, I use "makeindex %O -o %D %S"
   To make a ps file from a dvi file, I use "dvips %O -o %D %S"
   To make a ps file from a dvi file with landscape format, I use "dvips -tlandscape %O -o %D %S"
   To make a pdf file from a dvi file, I use "dvipdf %O %S %D"
   To make a pdf file from a ps file, I use "ps2pdf  %O %S %D"
   To view a pdf file, I use "open %S"
   To view a ps file, I use "NONE"
   To view a ps file in landscape format, I use "NONE"
   To view a dvi file, I use "NONE"
   To view a dvi file in landscape format, I use "NONE"
   To print a ps file, I use "lpr %O %S"
   To print a dvi file, I use "NONE $lpr_dvi variable is not configured to allow printing of dvi files"
   To print a pdf file, I use "lpr %O %S"
   To find running processes, I use "ps -ww -u scmbradley", 
      and the process number is at position 1
Notes:
  Command starting with "start" is run detached
  Command that is just "start" without any other command, is
     used under MS-Windows to run the command the operating system
     has associated with the relevant file.
  Command starting with "NONE" is not used at all
```

Comment: I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

For some reason in my distribution, the `-time` output is abbreviated:

```
'lualatex': time = 0.99
'makeindex a.idx': time = 0.02
'lualatex': time = 1.11
'lualatex': time = 1.07
```

As such, a simpler way is to simply grep for the string "Running" in `latexmk` output (it was mentioned above that the commands are *already* printed, just buried in the output):

```
$ latexmk    -lualatex  a 2> /dev/null |grep Running
Running 'lualatex  -recorder  "a.tex"'
Running 'makeindex -s gind.ist  -o "a.ind" "a.idx"'
Running 'lualatex  -recorder  "a.tex"'
Running 'lualatex  -recorder  "a.tex"'
```

(on e.g. Windows there would not be `grep` however.)

Of course it's trivial to construct some way for this to be wrong e.g. with a `\message` command in the TeX file, but that's not a large concern in normal use.

(side note, if you want to find out the commands of a "full run" do `latexmk -C a` to remove all auxiliary files beforehand; otherwise it might only do one run or similar.)

Comment: Remark: if you want `gind.ist` to be used by latexmk, refer to [indexing - How to say to latexmk to use makeindex with special parameter (-s -g) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314875/how-to-say-to-latexmk-to-use-makeindex-with-special-parameter-s-g)