# How to say to latexmk to use makeindex with special parameter (-s -g)

Tags: indexing, latexmk

I use makeindex routinely for a German book. A new latex package sanitize-umlaut allows now to write index terms without umlaute for example \index{Östrogene} instead of \index{Oestrogene@{Östrogene}}. To make it work properly one hat to use

```
makeindex -s german -g book
```

I would like to pass this parameters to latexmk. I do not see how to do this. The makeindex command is usually

```
makeindex book
```

I looked through latexmk questions but did not find an appropriate one.

Comment: I don't think there is an interface for it, you need to put it into a configuration file. Create `alt-german.rc`, in it add `$makeindex = 'makeindex -s german -g book';`, then call `latexmk` via `latexmk -r alt-german.rc ....`

Answer (score 9):

In the latexmk manual [[1](http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/latexmk-445.pdf), page 26], there is a configuration variable which can change the makeindex-command:

> $makeindex ["makeindex %O -o %D %S"]
>
> The indexprocessing program.

The value in square brackets is the default.

You can overwrite this default by creating a file `latexmkrc` in the directory of your document with the following code:

```
$makeindex = 'makeindex -s german -g %S';
```

Then call latexmk as usual. The defaults will be overwritten.

---

PS: You can define more options in the `latexmkrc`, for example `@default_files = ('document.tex')`, etc.

---

Edit: As Bernhard pointed out it's better to use `-g %S` instead of the hardcoded `-g book`

Comment: For flexibility the entry in latexmkrc should read  $makeindex = 'makeindex -s german -g %S';