# Compile using only one command

Tags: luatex, compiling, biber

Actually I need several commands to compile my Latex document:

```
lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error main
biber main
makeindex main
makeindex -s main.ist -t main.alg -o main.acr main.acn
makeindex -s main.ist -t main.glg -o main.gls main.glo
lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error main
lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error main #not sure if this is really needed
```

But I noticed that [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) can compile the document with a single run... Well, I can't see what Overleaf does in background but I assume it.

Is there a way to compile everything with a single command?

Of cause I can use a Bash script or Makefile. But I'm thinking of a way that also speeds up things. It's very slow to compile the document three times. Maybe there is a single step to build all things in one step.

Comment: one word: `latexmk` (that is what overleaf is using, and me as well on my Linux box)

Comment: have a look at https://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html

Comment: Oh, I remember, I tried it before. But I had issues: `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �\lst@EC� (U+9EBC)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
`. I don't have this error when using the bash commands instead.

Comment: Overleaf has documented its latexmk config: https://de.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_does_Overleaf_compile_my_project%3F

Comment: OK, I tried it again and found the cause. No it's working using latexmk and this config: ```$pdf_mode = 1;
@default_files = ('main.tex');
my $texinputs = defined $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'} ? $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'} : '';
$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'}='./tex//:'.$texinputs;
$pdflatex = 'lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error';
$clean_ext = "acn bbl dvi glo lol upa upb aux synctex.gz run.xml";
```

Comment: @daleif `latexmk` does not work well with `makeglossaries`.

Comment: @Foad since when? it works just fine for me.

Comment: @daleif here is the error message I get `Latexmk: Missing input file 'main.acr' (or dependence on it) from following:  No file main.acr.` when I run `latexmk -pdf -outdir=build main.tex`

Comment: @Foad please create your own question with MWE etc instead of highjacking someone elses question. And always test without build dirs, not all programme supports it.

Comment: @daleif I am not highjacking anything. You left a comment recommending `latexmk`, and I just pointed out a common issue with this tool for those folks who end up here. For my own work, I have already moved on to `ltx2any` on WSL2 and have written a small cmd/batch script that runs `pdflatex,` `makeglossaries,` and `biber` consecutively.

Comment: almost 5 years ago. And as mentioned I have no issues with it.

Comment: @daleif, could you please run the command `latexmk -pdf -outdir=build main.tex` on an MWE that includes glossaries and let me know if it still works?

Comment: @Foad Your earlier comment _reads_ like a new quetion, rather than a comment on daleif's one: I think that's what he's getting at. (And as he says, `latexmk` is very widely used.)

Comment: @Foad Output directory settings are regarded by many experienced (La)TeX users as a disaster

Comment: @JosephWright, thanks for the comment. Just for clarification: My comment was not intended to be a new question. I understand that `latexmk` is a very popular tool, and I know that building folders is widely frowned upon. Yet, coming from a C/C++/CMake background, I can't help but avoid contaminating my project folder with other temporary files.

Answer (score 2):

There are many automation tools which can be split into two categories:

## Automatically determine which commands are necessary

- latexmk
- ltx2any
- rubber
- ...

## User gives list of commands

- arara
- quick compile from texstudio (user can configure in preferences which commands are run)
- ...

Comment: But latexmk and ltx2any still run the commands like I'm doing, right?

Comment: @Michael They will recognise automatically which tools need to be run. If you need any special options for makeindex, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314877/199084

Comment: AFAIK the only one in this list that can automatically detect what commands must be run is ltx2any. latexmk has lots of issues with `makeglossaries`. texify does not work with BibLaTeX-biber. With rubber/arara you have to basically program the sequence of the necessary compilers in the headers of your .tex file or a separate configuration file. In that sense, they are no more different than a cmd-batch, PowerShell, or bash script.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is arara. Look at documentation:

https://ctan.org/pkg/arara

You can allways put compiling commands into "options" directive. I not entirely sure about the makeindex, but there is a rule to "compile" with it and I am pretty sure that those options you are using will be within arara automatic.