# Limit pdflatex execution time

Tags: pdftex

Is there any way to limit pdflatex execution time ?

It would be nice if the value could be added to the texmf file.

Comment: What do you mean by *limit `pdflatex`*?

Comment: Pdflatex runs for _x_ seconds. If there was an infinite loop, then being able to limit execution time would stop the compile.

Comment: @pmagunia: Why would there be an infinite loop when compiling?

Comment: @Werner the inifite loop could be caused by accident or a  possibly a malicious user

Comment: @Werner perhaps someone on the internet suggested adding `a\let\par\empty\hrule` to your document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You just became that "someone on the Internet"...

Comment: Related Infinite loop case studies [How to prolong compilation time while engaging in leisure activities?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122116/15717) and [Document requiring infinitely many compiler passes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30674/15717)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, what is the effect of your code?

Comment: @Sigur try it and see:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, is it safe? I'm typing a paper now!

Comment: @Sigur It will make tex loop forever, but so long as you can kill the job that's not a problem. It won't destroy any files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [arara: Refer Page 62 Chapter 7](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/arara/doc/arara-usermanual.pdf) there is an `--timeout n` flag that terminates the execution of any engine. I think there is no in built flag for `pdftex` engines I suppose

> "This flag sets an execution timeout for every
>    task. If the timeout is reached before the task
>   ends, arara will kill it and interrupt the process-
>   ing. The n value is expressed in milliseconds". From [arara User Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/arara/doc/arara-usermanual.pdf)

`arara` has been integrated with IDE's (Chapter 4 of User Manual) and it's author is [Paulo Cereda et al](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda)

Ex command line: `arara file.tex --log --verbose --timeout 10`
for 10 milli second run

Comment: Holy cow, I almost forgot `arara` had this option! `:)` Damn those authors.

Comment: @PauloCereda Credits to the Authors of arara manual that once read it goes directly into head and does not require multiple passes :)

Comment: @PauloCereda reading the manual is cheating :)

Comment: @cmhughes: C'mon Chris, I can't even remember what I had for lunch today. `:P`