# Challenge: Shortest Infinitesimally Unlikely Document: "ordinary" document forever requesting: "rerun to get cross-references right". t"

Tags: fun

Stop reading here if you do not like stupid yet amusing challenges.

Challenge: produces the shortest document yielding

```
 LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

No matter how many times it is run through `LaTeX`.

I presume there is a cheating solution by which you mess up with the reference information as read from the `.aux` file. It would be nice to see one.

The challenge in producing the shortest "non-cheating" solution might be in clever ways of searching for a needle in an enormously huge haystack: Those rare documents in which setting changing a referenced label, say from `1` to `2` manages, through the delicate layout algorithm, to change the referenced label back, i.e., from '2' to '1'.

---

**EDIT:** In view of [Document requiring infinitely many compiler passes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30674/document-requiring-infinitely-many-compiler-passes), which essentially solves the problem by a different kind of "cheating": forcing in and out text and blocks, using macros, I would rephrase:

- The shortest `LaTeX` document that requests forever: "rerun to get cross-references right", but please do so by using text only.  It is okay to use
  text generated by, e.g., `\lipsum`, but it is not okay to sneak in loops.

If memory serves me right, Lamport said in his book that the probability of such an incident is infinitesimal.

Comment: The shorter cheating document is, in full `\typeout{LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.}\stop`

Comment: The duplicate is a cheating solution: it does not produce a "real" document, i.e., with text such as lipsum, but rather some way of achieving the references changing cycle by forcibly insert huge text. Let me edit.

Comment: I do not understand your description of the solution posted in the duplicate, it does not depend on any text (other than it needs 5 pages as the cycle is between references to page 4 and 5) You could pad it to 5 pages using lipsum if you prefer.

Comment: All solutions use `\clearpage`, `\vspace`, or `figure` in one way or another. Here is an alternative description: : find sequence of text organized in paragraphs, that  has this property. If you okay this, I will edit it in.

Comment: there are no loops in the accepted answer, just a page reference that oscillates between 4 and 5 due to the reference text changing the page breaking

Comment: as I say, the accepted solution doesn't need \clearpage \vspace or figure, if you want to write 4 pages of paragraph text that would work as well, it's just less minimal.

Comment: Yes, but this solution uses a figure. In my alternative description, the request is to use text. Should we stress that this means "text", and only "text" so that challenge takers would not use ridiculous `\section` nesting to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40545/discussion-between-yossi-gil-and-david-carlisle).