# acronymns not showing up in latex document

Tags: glossaries, overleaf, acronyms

all. I am trying to get a list of acronyms to show up in my document. I have a main "thesis.tex" file where I would like to put the acronyms after the list of figures and tables.

In the preamble of the document, I have the following:

```
\usepackage[]{uahdis,chngpage,units,bm,hhline,rotating,verbatim,amsfonts,amssymb,xspace,url,natbib}
\usepackage[]{indentfirst,layouts, booktabs, enumerate, gensymb}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
```

After begin document, I have this:

```
\begin{document}

%   Here comes the stuff that goes before the main content
\frontmatter

\pagestyle{plain}

\maketitle

\copyrightpage

%MWT - UAH Approval Form
\approvalpage


%   Include my abstract
\include{./FRONT/abstract}

%   Include my acknowledgements
\include{./FRONT/acknowledgments}

%   Make a Table of Contents
\tableofcontents

%   Make a List of Figures
\listoffigures

%   Make a List of Tables
\listoftables

%   print the acronyms
\include{./FRONT/acronyms}
\clearpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

%   Make a List of Symbols (Comment out if unwanted)
\include{./FRONT/symbols}
```

In a separate folder with filepath `./FRONT/acronyms.tex'`, I have the following code:

```
\newacronym{ALEXI}{ALEXI}{Atmosphere Land Exchange Inverse}
\newacronym{ESI}{ESI}{Evaporative Stress Index}
```

However, I get a List of tables and a list of symbols and a blank page with no acronyms

For example:

Here is the tables on page xi:

[image]

Here is the missing acronyms on page xii:

[image]

Here is the list of symbols that works:

[image]

I would like the list of acronyms to be added just after the List of Tables. Everything else in the document works fine. I am unsure of what I need to do to get these acronyms to show up.

One thing I have noticed, and not sure if it is important is that my `acronyms.tex` file is mising a .bak. I am wondering if this has anything to do with it? For example:

[image]

I am using Overleaf to write my thesis. Is there something that I need to do specific to Overleaf to get it to work? I have tried clearing the log cache with no success.

Comment: Just like your symbols question, did you put the acronyms in the document?

Comment: I figured it out. See comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671398/288062

Comment: The dot bak files are backup files made at some point by Overleaf I think.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by doing a few things. First I used the drop-down menu on the overleaf compile button and turned on "auto compile."

Then, I changed the following code under the comment listed below:

```
% print the acronyms
\glsaddall %adds all the entries to the glossary
\printglossary
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist]
```

For some reason, it worked.I think that one reason is that I did not need to include the acronyms page specifically.

Comment: I think you do need to include the acronyms file somewhere (maybe is it done from some other file?) But you must also indicate where you want the listing appear with `\printglossary` like you did with the list of figures or the list of tables. I suspect you print the symbols from some inclusion... Also be aware that such listing need you compile 2 or 3 times...

Comment: How do I do it so that it will only compile once?

Comment: @gildux also, how do I make sure it appears somewhere? What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, you cannot make it compile once... At first, references (figures, tables, sections, cites, etc.) are created or updated (think of when material move from some page to another). In a second pass, the counters and pointers are updated with the previously computed values. At that step, if you have dynamic macros, you'll need au third compilation to let them have updated values. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573761/23418 and comments.