# --aux-directory simulation on Texlive

Tags: texlive, miktex

I use TeX Live and as you know `--aux-directory` works only on MiKTeX, is there any way to simulate `--aux-directory=dir`.

Also I think that TeX Live and MiKTeX are the only distributions. Why are they different in this case? Is there any other significant difference between them?

Comment: For your first question, does [Need *.aux file in separate folder](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7265) help? For your second question have a look at [What are the advantages of TeX Live over MiKTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20036)