# How to compile creating externalized figures files from pgfplots in a given folder?

Tags: pgfplots, compiling, auxiliary-files

I'm working on a project on LaTeX which includes heavy externalization of `pgfplots` figures, so I've hidden everything in a `tex` subfolder of the main one and work only there. Every time, though, I have to scan through all the files (they're like an hundred or more) to search my `.tex` source or my custom `.sty` files.

I've found the option `output-directory` and I'm using it, but it only moves the main `.log` and `.aux` files, and the `.md5` from the externalized figures, however every other `.pdf` and `.log` relative to any single figure created with `pgfplots` is still in the main directory.

I usually compile straight from the shell and use `vim` to write the files. Can I do this?

Comment: What about [Need `*.aux` file in separate folder](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7265/5764)?

Comment: The question title asks about moving `.aux`, `.log` files to a separate folder, but the question body text says you're already doing this and you want to move externalized figure files instead. Which is it?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I was going to ask how to move all of them but then I found a solved question for the main `.aux` and `.log` but forgot to change the title. The question still stands for those other files.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the (remaining) question right, but do you mean `\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]`? This will put all files that will be created through the externalization to the given (sub)directory.

Comment: Yes, I figured it long ago I needed that `tikzexternalize` option, but I forgot I wrote this question, thank you. What should I do? Answer it myself?