# Texmaker on Mac, using "build" subdirectory

Tags: texmaker

Has anyone succeeded in using this option on Mac OS X?

I've always used it in my Windows computer since I hated seeing scrap files all over my folder. It worked just fine, but now that I'm trying to do the same in my Mac machine, it doesn't work. I have two independent Mac machines and neither of them lets it work.

Comment: Were you using MiKTeX on Windows? If so, it has an [`--aux-directory`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7272/3345) flag not present in any TeX Live (including MacTeX).

Comment: Yes I was. I guess that solves the mystery, thanks!

Comment: You may be able to use latexmk and have it clean up after itself. But that will force full rebuilds of the document each time.