# Why does latexmk call PdfLatex for lualatex documents?

Tags: luatex, automation, latexmk

I prepared a `.latexmkrc` config

```perl
$lualatex='lualatex -synctex=1 %O %B';
$pdf_mode = 4;
$aux_dir = "temp/";
$out_dir = "out/";
$success_cmd = "rm %R.pdf && mv out/*.pdf tex/";

add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');

sub run_makeglossaries {
  if ( $silent ) {
    system "makeglossaries -q '$_[0]'";
  }
  else {
    system "makeglossaries '$_[0]'";
  };
}

push @generated_exts, 'glo', 'gls', 'glg';
push @generated_exts, 'acn', 'acr', 'alg';
$clean_ext .= ' %R.ist %R.xdy';
```

and compile a lualatex document with

```
latexmk -lualatex -gg -interaction=batchmode testx.tex
```

finally I get the message

```
Output written on testx.pdf (33 pages, 5058191 bytes).
SyncTeX written on testx.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on testx.log.
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  lualatex: (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'temp/testx.log'
Latexmk: Did not finish processing file 'testx.tex':
   (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'temp/testx.log'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
```

and wonder why it calls `pdflatex`. I would expect

```
lualatex failed to generate the expected...
```

System:

```
Linux Mint 18.2 (latest at 2017-07-28), TeXLive 2017

$ latexmk --version 
   Latexmk, John Collins, 19 Jan. 2017. Version 4.52c

$ tlmgr --version
   tlmgr revision 44452 (2017-06-05 01:45:39 +0200)
   tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2017
   TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2017
```

Comment: What does the log-file says? Was pdflatex or lualatex called?

Comment: With the examples you show, latexmk will definitely call lualatex.  The error message is misleading/out-of-date: you should interpret "(Pdf)LaTeX" in the message as meaning "whatever latex-like program was invoked".  The actual error you get about the log is often a consequence of using the -auxdir option when latex, lualatex etc don't support it (e.g., with the TeXLive distribution).  What OS and TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: @JohnCollins I guess Jonas might be using TeXLive  on linux distro https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/need-aux-file-in-separate-folder/83290#comment553452_83290

Comment: @texenthusiast So? The difference is Mik TeX vs. TeX Live. Does OS affect it and, if so, how? Perhaps you linked to the wrong place?

Comment: @texenthusiast If the OP is using shell functions, all bets are off. But that isn't specific to Linux. Could equally be OS X or any other Unix-ish system. Or Cygwin, possibly. And the setting shown in the post would be all wrong, of course.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The head of the logfile starts with `This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)  (format=lualatex 2017.6.26)`

Comment: @JohnCollins thank you. I think that is the answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in the comments.