# File extensions related to LaTeX, etc

Tags: context, auxiliary-files, tex-general

In addition to the `.tex` and `.dvi` or `.pdf` files, TeX/LaTeX/ConTeXt produces and uses lots of other files. What do they do? Which ones are used to create the document and which ones are automatically created by the compiler. What files can I safely delete?

Comment: What are the following files? .glg .alg .tdo .agr .acn .fls .fdb_latexmk .run.xml .acr .gls .glo .xdy I found the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53310/69025

Comment: I don't see an entry for files with a *.mw extension. What package(s) do they belong to? Thanks!

Comment: According to David Carlisle (https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/114), turns out the `.mw` extension is from the `morewrites` package. Apologies for asking ... trying to track down an obscure `Runaway text?` error that halts the compiler with a few mysterious, peculiar comments `\_morewrites_tex_immediate:w` `\_morewrites_tex_write:w` and `\g_morewrites_iow` output on the console that I don't understand.

Comment: It would be handy to have a basic `LaTeX` mechanism for indicating the extensions used for temporary files. This could be indicated via an `ASCII` file in the source code of a project. It would then be very easy to have all the extensions that can be removed.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

**`.fd`** = [Font definition](http://tex.loria.fr/ctan-doc/macros/latex/doc/html/fntguide/node22.html); used in generating the output.

**`.bst`** = BibTeX Style File (e.g., a certain journal's preferred Bibliography layout settings); used by BibTeX when generating the bibliography.

**`.aux`** = LaTeX auxiliary file; created when LaTeX is run, these contain information LaTeX records which is then used by either BibTeX or LaTeX itself on later runs (e.g., about cross-references), and can contain other things as well. This file is created by running LaTeX but also used the next time LaTeX is run. It can be deleted, but then you may need to run multiple times in the future to regenerate it.

**`.bbl`** = Bibliography; this is what is outputted by BibTeX for insertion into LaTeX the next time LaTeX is run.

**`.blg`** = Bibliography (BibTeX) log -- just like `.log` but for BibTeX; generated by BibTeX and can be safely deleted if there's no need to check it for errors.

**`.brf`** = BackReference file for the backref package, I think. I'm not very familiar with these, but I suspect they're created by LaTeX when a file using that package is compiled.

**`.cls`** = Documentclass (like article, or report - if you have them cluttering up your folders, you must use a lot of custom classes for individual journals or universities, etc.) This is obviously used to generate the output.

**`.dtx`** = Documented source file; can be used to generate a LaTeX package or other file along with its associated documentation.

Of these, `.aux` and `.blg` can  be safely deleted. Probably `.bbl` too if you don't mind rerunning BibTeX and have access to the `.bib` files needed. The rest should not be deleted but maybe moved somewhere more appropriate. In particular `.fd`, `.cls`, and `.dtx` are better taking up space on a (personal) TeX tree, not in the folder of the document you're working on.

Comment: Thanks very much. Actually, I forgot another extension which is .lbl. Could you please edit your answer to tell me what it is?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what a .lbl file is. Probably something specific to a package, like .brf, and the letters suggest something having to do with labels. What packages are you using for things like that? Almost all of these are plain text files, so you could open it and see what's inside.

Comment: Do we now know what package produces `lbl` files?

Answer (score 52):

## General

### Manually created

- **`.tex`:** The document itself
  Created by you.

### Automatically created

- **`.aux`:** An auxiliary file that saves information for the creation of ToC, references, indices, bibliographies and other things like that. It is reread in the next compiling to create the ToC, references etc.
  Created by `(pdf/xe/lua)(la)tex`
- **`.toc`:** An auxiliary file that stores the Table of Contents, read in on subsequent runs to create the actual ToC.
  Created by `(pdf)latex`, `xe(la)tex`.
- **`.lof`:** An auxiliary file that stores the List of Figures, read in on subsequent runs to create the actual LoF.
  Created by `(pdf)latex`, `xe(la)tex`.
- **`.lot`:** An auxiliary file that stores the List of Tables, read in on subsequent runs to create the actual LoT.
  Created by `(pdf)latex`, `xe(la)tex`.
- **`.log`:**  Stors all messages of the compilation, like errors and warnings. It’s used by most Editors / LaTeX IDEs to show the errors in you document.
  Created by `(pdf)latex`, `xe(la)tex`.
- **`.pdf`:**  The common output format for your document.
  Created by `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `ps2pdf`, `dvipdf`.

Answer (score 48):

## Bibliographies

### Manually created

- **`.bib`:**  The data base file containing your bibliography entries.
  Created by you.
- **`.bst`**: BibTeX style file.
  Determines how the bibliography looks (usually downloaded from somewhere).
- **`.bbx`:** A `biblatex` bibliography style.
  Created by users.
- **`.cbx`:** A `biblatex` cite style.
  Created by users.

### Automatically created

- **`.bbl`**: bibliography environment, generated by BibTeX.
  This is what the call to `bibtex` produces and what is included into your document by the `\bibliography` command.
- **`.blg`:** `bibtex` and `biber` log file.
  Created by `bibtex`/`biber`.
- **`.bcf`:** `biblatex` control file.
- **`.run.xml`:** `biber` XML file.
- **`-blx.bib`:** `biblatex` control file.

Answer (score 42):

### `beamer` special files

In addition to the standard `.aux`, `.log`, and `.toc` files, a `beamer` document will also create the following auxiliary files:

- **`.nav`**: contains the information needed for the navigation bar hyperlinks.
- **`.vrb`**: will contain the verbatim material when `fragile` (containing verbatim material) frames.
- **`.snm`**: will contain information that will be used by `\pgfimage`
  to include actual slides when using the `beamerarticle` package.
- **`.out`**: contains information about the sectional units that will be used to write the outlines.

Answer (score 31):

## General Layout and Package files

### Manually created

- **`.cls`:** Class files containing settings for you document and providing the basic macros for the mark up, e.g `\section`.
  Created by users or `latex` with an `ins` file.
- **`.def`:** Collection of a list of similar definitions, that would make a `sty` file long and unreadable. See [What does the .def file do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55647/what-does-the-def-file-do), and [When to use ".sty" extension and when to use ".def"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51904/when-to-use-sty-extension-and-when-to-use-def).
- **`.dtx`:**  Source file containing template files, like classes and styles and their documentation.
  Created by users.
- **`.ins`:**  installation file to extract template files out of a `dtx` file. 
  Created by users.
- **`.sty`:**  Style file containing macro definitions and other extensions for your document. 
  Created by users or `latex` with an `ins` file.

### Automatically created

Comment: These are not templates!

Comment: @JosephWright: Maybe it’s the wrong word, I’m no native speaker. Pleas change it if you find a better title :-)

Answer (score 23):

Some further extension you might encounter depending on what packages you are using:

- **`.soc`** - package [**changes**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/changes)
- **`.fdb_latexmk`** - compile tool [**latexmk**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk)
- **`.fls`** - running latex with [**$ latex -recorder**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdflatex)
- **`.spl`** - documentclass [**elsarticle**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle) (Elsevier journals)
- **`.auxlock`** - tikzlibrary [**external**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz)
- **`.xwm`** - package [**xwatermark**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xwatermark)
- **`.tdo`** - package [**todonotes**](https://ctan.org/pkg/todonotes)

Answer (score 12):

I think you don't need to worry about files other than `*.tex`, `*.cls` and `*.sty`.

1. `*.tex` is the extension for input files in which you put your document content and format. You can have more than one input file for your project. But only one input file can contain `\documentclass` call. The input file contains `\documentclass` call is called as your main input file.
2. `*.cls` is the extension for documentclass containing layout settings and commands. There are many documentclass, such as `article`, `book`, `minimal`, `report`, etc. From within your main input file, you call this document class using the command `\documentclass{book}`, for example. Calling `\documentclass{book}` means you want to create a book project. In book project, you will have some settings such as chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, frontmatter, mainmatter, backmatter, etc. Other documentclass also has different settings.
3. `*.sty` is the extension for package containing class-agnostic commands. There are many packages. Each provides different purposes and works indendepently. For example, if you want to draw Euclid diagram for your project, you can use `pst-eucl.sty`. From within your main input file, you call this package by using `\usepackage{pst-eucl}`.

As the rule of thumbs: You may accidently lose files other than your input files, image files, data files. If you lost `*.cls` and `*.sty`, download again from the internet. If you lost `*.aux`, just compile again your input file.

Comment: I don't understand why someone wouldn't need to worry about .bst or .fd files, etc. Deleting those could definitely cause problems.

Comment: @frabjous. I don't say the other files are not important. :-)

Comment: @frabjous: I would read "don't worry about them" as "leave them be: don't try to understand what's going on with them, for now, just treat them as part of the magic of TeX", certainly not as "they're not important; you may as well delete them"!

Comment: Fair enough! Just so long as it is clear, which it wasn't to me, and may not have been to others. (It is now, thank!.)

Comment: What about `.bst`'s?

Answer (score 11):

## ConTeXt MkIV related files:

### User-Input Files

- **`.tex`:** For content and typesetting instructions.
- **`.cld`:** For ConTeXt Lua Documents
- **`.xml`:** For XML data (related: `.xhtml`)

### Macro package files

- **`.mkiv`:** Code for MkIV
- **`.mkvi`:** Code for MkIV written with named variables `\def\macro#{val1}#{val2}` rather than `\def\macro#1#2`, etc.)
- **`.lua`:** Lua code for MkIV
- **`.lfg`:** *Goodies* for fonts (used for creating virtual fonts and changing parameters defined in fonts)
- **`.mpiv`:** Metapost code for MkIV

### Automatically generated

- **`.tuc`:** Data stored for multiple passes, ToC, etc.
- **`.log`:** Log file

You can safely delete the `.tuc` and `.log` files. These can be automatically deleted if you run

```
context --purgeall
```

Answer (score 9):

## Related questions

- [Egad! What are all those files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53240/4918)
- [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11123/4918)
- [‘Bundle’ TeX output in a directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2977/4918)
- [Deleting external/auxiliary files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24785/4918)

Answer (score 8):

The following is a list of most of the common file extensions used for UNIX *(La)TeX* files and what they mean. They are in the order in which you are likely to come across them rather than alphabetic order.

- **`.tex`**: denotes a *source* file for any *flavour* of *TeX*.
- **`.cls`**: denotes a *LaTeX 2e* **class** file.
- **`.clo`**: denotes a *LaTeX 2e* **class option** file. usually **options** associated with a **class** are defined in a `.cls` file, but occasionally they are defined in separate `.clo` files.
- **`.sty`**: denotes a *LaTeX* (or *AmS-TeX*) **package/style** file. *LaTeX 2.09* made no distinction between **classe**s and **package**s ... all such files were *style* files - hence the suffix. *LaTeX 2e* has retained the suffix for what it now terms as **packages**.
- **`.log`**: denotes a *log* file for any *flavour* of *TeX*.
- **`.aux`**: denotes an *aux*iliary file. generated by running latex (or etex) on a *source* file. It typically contains information latex needs on a second pass to construct `\refs` and `\cites` and information that bibtex needs to construct a `.bbl` file.
- **`.toc`**: denotes a *t*able *o*f *c*ontents file. generated by latex when the source file contains the line `\tableofcontents`.
- **`.lot`**: denotes a *l*ist *o*f *t*ables file. generated by latex when the source file contains the line `\listoftables` (Similar to a .toc file.)
- **`.lof`**: denotes a *l*ist *o*f *f*igures file. generated by latex when the source file contains the line `\listoffigures` (Similar to a .toc file.)
- **`.bib`**: denotes a *BibTeX* source file. such files contain the database from which the `.bbl` bibliography file is generated.
- **`.bst`**: denotes a *BibTeX style* file. the style in which bibtex presents the `.bbl` bibliography file.
- **`.bbl`**: denotes a *(La)TeX* bibliography file. usually generated by bibtex.
- **`.blg`**: denotes a *BibTeX* log file.
- **`.idx`**: denotes a *MakeIndex* **index** source file. contains `\indexentry` commands generated by a first pass of a *TeX* source file through a flavour of *TeX*.
- **`.ist`**: denotes a *MakeIndex style* file. needed only when the default manner in which makeindex processes an `.idx` file needs to be over-ridden, e.g. when makeindex is used for generating a `.gls` glossary file.
- **`.ind`**: denotes a *(La)TeX* **index** file. usually generated by makeindex.
- **`.ilg`**: denotes a *MakeIndex* log file.
- **`.glo`**: denotes a *MakeIndex* **glossary** source file. contains `\glossaryentry` commands generated by a first pass of a *TeX* source file through a flavour of *TeX*.
- **`.gls`**: denotes a *TeX* **glossary** file. usually generated by makeindex, which needs an appropriate `.ist` file to over-ride the *MakeIndex* defaults that produce indexes.
- **`.glg`**: denotes a *MakeIndex* **glossary** log file.
- **`.dtx`**: denotes a file containing *(La)TeX* **package**(s)/**class**(es) together with its documentation. Running *(La)TeX* on the file usually generates the `.dvi` documentation. An accompanying `.ins` file calls docstrip.tex to strip the *(La)TeX* **package**(s)/**class**(es) from the `.dtx` file and sometimes also a `.drv` file.
- **`.ins`**: denotes a *(La)TeX* *ins*tall file. Running *(La)TeX* on the file strips **package** or **class** files from accompanying `.dtx` files(s).
- **`.drv`**: denotes a *(La)TeX driver* file. Sometimes stripped from a `.dtx` file by running *(La)TeX* on an `.ins` file. Running *(La)TeX* on the .drv file generates the `.dvi` documentation.

Answer (score 4):

### Files generated by some other packages

#### [changebar](http://ctan.org/pkg/changebar)

- **`.cb2`:** Coordinates of "points" in the text for beginning and ending stretches marked by a change-bar on the side.
- **`.cb`:**  Some other kind of history / points file (package documentation is not very clear about it)

Answer (score 3):

## (r)(e)ledmac/(r)(e)ledpar files

- `.1, .1R, .2, .2R` file storing metadata about line break and critical notes. One by `\beginnumbering...\endnumbering`
- `.eledsec1, .elesdec2` etc. File for the `eledsection` and related commands
- `.Aend, .Bend, .Cend` etc. File for the endnotes of series A, B, C etc.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the other answers mentioned here, I'd like to add the extensions `mtc[0-9]` and `ptc` to the list here.

Files with these extension names are created by the [`titletoc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package, usually used in books and long articles to obtain a toc within each chapter.

I guess they stand for `mini toc` (with the suffix denoting chapter number) and `partial toc` (i.e. the global toc that gets continuously updated during the build process as each chapter is getting built).

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned `.synctex.gz` (used by synctex to let you associate locations in your output with your source) even in the comments.  I'm just adding it for completeness