# What does the .def file do?

Tags: packages

When downloading a new package and running

```
tex packagename.ins
```

you always get a bunch of files, including the `.def` file. It's also mentioned in the `.sty` file. Apparently it's a definition being used for something.

What exactly is it for though? And can it be omitted when sharing the LaTeX project?

Comment: It depends on the package concerned. Usually, any `.def` will be needed, and so you should install them.

Comment: See also [When to use “.sty” extension and when to use “.def”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51904/2975)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Usually files with the extension `.def` collect long lists of similar definitions, that would make a `.sty` file long and unreadable, or that can possibly be shared with other packages.

If `tex packagename.ins` creates a `.def` file, then this *is* part of the package structure and mustn't be omitted.

A typical example are the `<encoding>enc.def` files, such as `t1enc.def` loaded by `fontenc`:

```
\ProvidesFile{t1enc.def}
 [2005/09/27 v1.99g
         Standard LaTeX file]
\DeclareFontEncoding{T1}{}{}
\DeclareTextAccent{\`}{T1}{0}
\DeclareTextAccent{\'}{T1}{1}
\DeclareTextAccent{\^}{T1}{2}
\DeclareTextAccent{\~}{T1}{3}
<...>
\DeclareTextSymbol{\NG}{T1}{141}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\OE}{T1}{215}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\O}{T1}{216}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\SS}{T1}{223}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\TH}{T1}{222}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\ae}{T1}{230}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\dh}{T1}{240}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\dj}{T1}{158}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\guillemotleft}{T1}{19}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\guillemotright}{T1}{20}
<...>
```

where having the long list in a separate file makes it more easily maintainable and searchable. Similarly `inputenc` uses `.def` files for lists of pairings between input characters and their connected output.

Some other packages use some `.def` files for "context dependent" code. Examples are `graphics`/`graphicx` and `hyperref` that put the engine dependent code (for `latex`/`dvilualatex`, `pdflatex`/`lualatex` and `xelatex`) in `.def` files such as `pdftex.def` and `dvips.def` (`graphics`) or `hpdftex.def` and `hdvips.def` (`hyperref`).

Other packages, notably `bidi`, `xepersian` or `minitoc`, use `.def` files to load code depending on what packages are loaded in the document.

In some cases perhaps an extension such as `.sto` ("style option", modelled after `.clo` used by the standard classes) might have been preferable, but tradition has its influence. So long as the names are unique, the extension used is irrelevant.

Comment: Also compiler dependent things are put into `.def` files and the correct one is then loaded (e.g. `pdftex.def` if `pdflatex` is used)