# Adding a course name to an article

Tags: titles

I'm writing a research paper for a class, and I want to know if there is a way to write in the course name into the title section of the article in overleaf? 
For example, if I want it to show up like this:

Title of Paper

Name

Math 101

Date

I tried using `\affil` like this:

```
\title{Title of Paper}
\author{Name}
\affil{Math 101}
\date{May 7, 2020}
```

but this didn't work, everything but the Math 101 disappeared.

Comment: Hi @Lewis. Can you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of what you are looking for?

Comment: \affil will most likely not be defined. You can use \title{Paper Title \\ math 101} for a start but should definitely follow the link given in the answer below and read it before reading the answer itself.

Comment: In some cases, adding it to the title will work.

Answer (score 2):

Define your own title with -- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\course#1{\gdef\@course{#1}}
\def\@course{\@latex@warning@no@line{Hey you, no \noexpand\course given}}
\def\@maketitle{%
    \newpage \null  \vskip 2em%
    \begin{flushright}%
        \let\footnote\thanks
        \vskip 1.5em%
        {\large  \lineskip .5em%
            \begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}}%
                \@author    
            \end{tabular}\par 
            \begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}}%
                {\sffamily \@course}   
            \end{tabular}\par 
            \par}%
        \vskip .5em%
        {\small\@date}\par\bigskip%
        {\LARGE\scshape \@title \par\bigskip\hrule}%
    \end{flushright}%
    \par   \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother


\title{Some long Wonderfull Title}
\course{UFO affairs\thanks{Area 51}} 
\author{Clever Reporter\thanks{No dot disturb.}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use \def in a LaTeX document?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55652/197451

Comment: Why are you using \def to define new and *overwrite existing* commands? Why don't you use newcommand?