# Undefined control sequence ``\let`` in ``hyperref`` included after ``unicode-math``

Tags: hyperref, luatex, unicode-math

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
aaa
\end{document}
```

When I compile it with `lualatex`, I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Url@FormatString 

l.5037 \let
         \HyOrg@url\url
?
```

If I put `hyperref` before `unicode-math`, I get a different error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Url@FormatString 

l.2317 }
```

The strange part is, the first document (more complicated one to be exact, the one I've reduced to this example) worked for me just yesterday. I have not updated any part of the system; I tried reverting back to previous commits and that did not help either. Does anyone know what can cause this problem?

System details:

- OSX 10.8.5
- TexLive 2013
- luatex r30581, hyperref r28213, unicode-math r30504

Edit: the result of `\listfiles`:

```
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
unicode-math.sty    2013/05/04 v0.7e Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   expl3.sty    2013/07/28 v4582 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2012/12/07 v4346 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
  luatex.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 LuaTeX basic definition package (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
luatex-loader.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
l3basics.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2013/07/24 v4565 L3 Argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Token lists
   l3seq.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Integers
 l3quark.sty    2013/07/21 v4564 L3 Quarks
   l3prg.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Control structures
 l3clist.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Property lists
   l3msg.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Messages
  l3file.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 File and I/O operations
  l3skip.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2013/07/09 v4521 L3 Floating points
   l3box.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty    2013/07/24 v4576 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
  xparse.sty    2013/07/28 v4582 L3 Experimental document command parser
l3keys2e.sty    2013/07/28 v4582 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
fontspec.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
luaotfload.sty    2013/07/23 v2.3b OpenType layout system
luatexbase.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Resource management for the LuaTeX macro progr
ammer
luatexbase-compat.sty    2011/05/24 v0.4 Compatibility tools for LuaTeX
luatexbase-modutils.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Module utilities for LuaTeX
luatexbase-loader.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Lua module loader for LuaTeX
luatexbase-regs.sty    2011/05/24 v0.4 Registers allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-attr.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Attributes allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-cctb.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Catcodetable allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-mcb.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Callback management for LuaTeX
fontspec-patches.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
fontspec-luatex.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu2enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu2lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many othe
r characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu2lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
fontspec.cfg
catchfile.sty    2011/03/01 v1.6 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
  fix-cm.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
unicode-math-luatex.sty    
lualatex-math.sty    2013/08/03 v1.3 Patches for mathematics typesetting with Lu
aLaTeX
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
unicode-math-table.tex
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    1999/03/02  ver 1.4  Verb mode for urls, email addresses, and fi
le names
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
smallcaps.out
smallcaps.out
```

Comment: Have you set up \hyperbaseurl yet?

Comment: No, I've never used it. Could you elaborate? From its documentation it is not clear why I should set it to anything.

Comment: If you remove the `.aux` (and [other associated files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53240/5764)), do you still get the same problem? I can't seem to replicate your problem (the [MWE](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) compiles without problem under XeLaTeX and LauLaTeX.

Comment: Yes, it persists after I remove all the temp files. Speaking of XeLaTeX, I tried it as well, and it shows the same error.

Comment: @Bogdan: Could you include `\listfiles` and extract the contents from your `.log` after `*File list*` and include it in your post?

Comment: @Werner: included.

Comment: Your version of `url.sty` is ancient: something is up here. Check through the log and find where it's being loaded from: mine is in `<installation directory>/tex/latex/url/url.sty`.

Comment: @JosephWright: thank you, this was the root of the issue. Turns out I dismissed some of the evidence as insignificant, and incorrectly stated that I have not changed the system. I will create an answer now, for posterity.

Comment: @Bogdan No problem: I've seen the 'old `url` copies' business before, so as soon as I read your question had an idea what might be the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My statement that "I have not updated any part of the system" was not entirely correct. I have installed `latex2html` package through `homebrew`, which, quite unexpectedly, [installs several style files into the user-local TeX home directory](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/22808). Among these files is an ancient version of `url.sty` which seems to conflict with pretty much everything. Removing this style file fixes the issue.

Comment: The last update to the [home page](http://www.latex2html.org) of the LaTeX2HTML project is dated 2001-09-25; it seems, if not dead, deeply asleep. For conversion to HTML, `tex4ht` is much better.