# Use of different output files in LaTeX (pdflatex)

Tags: auxiliary-files

When I use pdflatex, I get a bunch of files:

```
test.aux  
test.log  
test.out  
test.pdf  
test.tex  
test.toc
```

The .tex file and the .pdf file have an obvious use, but what do the other files do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best thing is to open these files with some text editor. For example log file contains logs from compiler, toc file is something like 'table of chapters' because as you can see there is a chapters' and sections' list used in a tex file and so on. I have additionally lof file (list of figures) and lot file (list of tables).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7770/file-extensions-of-latex-related-files http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53240 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `.aux` is the the "auxiliary" file and is used for (among other things) tracking cross-references made with `\label` and `\ref`.  This file is why you need to run `pdflatex` twice to make the references resolve.  The first pass writes data about the references to the `.aux` file and the second reads the `.aux` file and uses that to generate the necessary references.  Generally, anything that needs to wait for the entire document to be generated (like page numbers) is written to `.aux` so it can be added in on a later pass.
- `.log` contains a log of what `pdflatex` did.  You can find things like error messages and a list of what packages got loaded in here.
- `.out` is used to store extra information for the PDF.  For example the bookmarks in the PDF file are generated using this file.
- `.toc` is like `.aux` but only used for the table of contents, since the proper page numbers can't be known until the PDF has been generated.  There are likewise `.lof` and `.lot` files for lists of figures and lists of tables.

Except for the `.tex` file these are all generated by `pdflatex` and can be safely deleted.