# LaTeX Compilation

Tags: auxiliary-files

Why does LaTeX generate the following files:

1. aux file
2. log file
3. out file

I believe that the log file would keep the errors incase if the tex file had it but incase if it already was generated then why the log file is created and there overheads of aux and out file. Wouldn't the tex file and the pdf file be sufficient?(and a necessary log file)

Comment: Because LaTeX requires often a second run for collecting label, TOC etc. information. It is quite convenient to split this to the 'helper' (aux) file and the other information to `.log`

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7770 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152282 are very related. You can even browse this side for the tag "auxiliary-files" (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auxiliary-files)