# I can't get rid of the "Misplaced alignment tab character &." error with jurabib in texmaker

Tags: texmaker, jurabib

When i was adding something to my bib file i made an honest mistake and wrote

```
publisher = {International Journal of Physical Distribution & Logistics Management},
```

This lead to the "Misplaced alignment tab character &." error which i totally can understand. I then changed it to:

```
publisher = {International Journal of Physical Distribution \& Logistics Management},
```

But the error remained what somehow surprised me. After fiddling aroung with it for almost an hour i gave in and just changed it to

```
publisher = {International Journal of Physical Distribution and Logistics Management},
```

And even after doing this and restarting texmaker the problem remains.

The error message is the following:

> ! Misplaced alignment tab character &.  ...l Journal of
>   Physical Distribution & Logistics Management\prot... l.152 ...
>   recommended by Lin et al. \footcite{abc} The general idea is to br...
>   I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark here. If you
>   just want an ampersand, the remedy is simple: Just type "I\&" now. But
>   if some right brace up above has ended a previous alignment
>   prematurely, you're probably due for more error messages, and you
>   might try typing "S" now just to see what is salvageable.

It refers to the tex file and not to the bib file. I don't know if that matters but in the line 152 is no & sign whatsoever...

The entry in the bib file looks like that:

```
@Book{abc,
author = {Binshan, Lin and James, Collins and Robert K., Su},
title = {Supply chain costing: an activity-based perspective},
publisher = {International Journal of Physical Distribution \& Logistics Management},
year = {2001},
url = {http://elogistics.lhu.edu.tw/may/course/94_2/logistics/3B/D92425250/%E7%89%A9%E7%AE%A1%E6%9C%9F%E5%88%8A.pdf},
note = {20 Apr. 2015. 11:41 UTC -3 },
}
```

Is there another problem with the % sign?

The weirdest of it all is that it actually produces the pdf file correctly. I just have to open it "manually".

I have honestly no idea what to do anymore...

Comment: The fact that the error remained may be due to faulty auxiliary files. Try deleting all of these and recompile.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by a corrupt aux file.

Comment: I would be happy to close the question. I just don't know how to do it and i didn't know that the problem was a corrupt aux file.

Comment: @werner But the `.aux` file only contains the key to the reference, not the reference itself, right? Or did you mean the `.bbl` file?

Comment: @U.Windl: See [Egad! What are all those files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53240/5764) for a list of auxiliary files. You can delete all of them and then recompile your project using the appropriate additions (depending on whether you have a bibliography and/or an index).