# Beginner with latex: what are files .bbl, .toc, aux, .blg, .log used for?

Tags: external-files

When i compile a file, with `.tex` file other ones are produced. 
I know that log files contains warnings and errors (and more things i do not know), also that .bibl files are related with some bibliography, but *have them any common usage or something to be aware of?*
A short explanation of them will be ok, i am only starting with it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53240/egad-what-are-all-those-files perhaps

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7770/file-extensions-related-to-latex-etc possibly?

Comment: @JosephWright the first one was not useful for me. The second is good, thanks!