# What do you guys do with all the files what are automatically exported with .tex?

Tags: texshop, format-files, multiple-files

Following these posts: [Egad! What are all those files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53240/egad-what-are-all-those-files), [File extensions related to LaTeX, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7770/file-extensions-related-to-latex-etc) etc. I would like to know whether I am supposed to keep these or delete them, and also **is there a way to to them to export together in one folder**. It's very messy when I have multiple .tex files in one file and have to sort them into their separate sub folders. Can they be exported under a folder automatically? Can I chose which ones not to export automatically?

I am using TexShop

Comment: I have some .gitignore files to ignore them, but beside this I do nothing at all, I simply leave them there. Some editors have buttons to clean up, and scripts like latexmk have clean up options too, but I seldom use this.

Comment: you can get tex to write auxiliary files into a separate directlory but I strongly advise against it. It vastly complicates teh workflow for no benefit. If you write the files to a non-standard place you have to configure every program, tex, makeindex, bibtex, biber, ....  to find them.

Comment: I have recently started using LaTeX, so I may not be the most reliable user for this type of question, but I can bring my own experience.
To organize my documents I use VSC with a plugin that also allows me to automatically delete all the LaTeX-related extension files (to latch on to what @UlrikeFischer said).

Comment: If you are using MiKTeX or TeX you can use `--output-directory=dir`, so the output files will be in this directory (including the `.pdf` `.dvi` file). If you want only the aux files in that directory, in MiKTex you can also use `--aux-directory=dir`. I set the dir as a hidden folder like .build so it doesn't cause me inconvenience

Comment: @LukeTheWolf what is the advantage of deleting the files? If you delete the `.aux` `.bib` etc it just means that it takes longer to produce the document if you come back to the sources later.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use that command only when the project build enters a loop. 
I set up my IDE so that it automatically compiles whenever a project file is saved.
Because I may have made some typing errors, it happens that the main file fails to complete the file build and gets stuck on the main page.
Otherwise, I never use it, I put everything in a .gitignore file and share the repository without the extension files.

Comment: @LukeTheWolf oh "make clean" yes that can be necessary but the question is I think about routuinely hiding `.aux` and  `.log` just because they are there, not because they give errors.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, of course, I understood that too. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The sense I wanted to give to what I said before is that I usually organize the files in an editor and that, as Ulrike said, I use (if necessary) a command preset by the plugin to do a cleaning.
It was not my intention to say that I delete auxiliary files every time, because obviously, that would not bring any advantage.