# What is newline symbol in beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

If I use **\\ or $\newline$** in beamer inside a tikzpicture, I get the following error:

**Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{frame}**

What is correct use of it?

My tikz code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structuresmallcapsserif}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red!80!black,bg=red!20!white}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=7 cm,
                semithick, scale = 0.4, transform shape]


\node[initial,state] (A)                    {$s_0$};
\node[state]         (B) [above right of=A] {$s_1$};
\node[state]         (C) [below right of=A] {$s_2$};
\node[state]         (D) [below right of=B] {$s_3$};
\node[state]         (E) [above right of=D] {$s_4$};
\node[state]         (F) [below right of=D] {$s_5$};


  \path (A) 
    edge [left] node [blue, pos=0.5, sloped, above] {$0 \rightarrow [x = x.0.0]$} (B)
    edge [left] node [cyan, pos=0.8]{$1 \rightarrow [x = x.0.1]$} (C)(B) 
    edge [loop above] node [align=center] {$0 \rightarrow$ \\ $[x = x.0]$ }   (B)
    edge [bend right,left] node  {$1 \rightarrow [x = x.1]$ }   (C)
    edge [] node [red, pos=0.2] {$\$  \rightarrow  [x = x.0.\$]$ } (D);   

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Currently, your code doesn't involve Beamer.  Please add a minimal working example that includes all important aspects of the situation.

Comment: Once having changed the unknown `stealth'` arrow tip, your code compiles fine. `:)`

Comment: Even after removing stealth', I am getting the same error. :(

Comment: Please, could you provide a [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`?

Comment: Sorry for that. I have edited the question.

Comment: @user1280282 do you get the error with the *exact* code you posted or do the error appears in you actual document with some more code?

Comment: @user1280282: Delete all the auxiliary files created from a compile (mainly `<jobname>.aux`) (see [File extensions of LaTeX-related files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7770/5764)) and try to recompile. If the problem persists, we would need more information. For example, add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass{beamer}` and copy the contents in the `.log` *after* `**File List**` and include it as part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
edge [loop above] node [align=center] {$0 \rightarrow$ $\\$ $[x = x.0]$ }   (B)
```

to

```
edge [loop above] node [align=center] {$0 \rightarrow$ \\ $[x = x.0]$ }   (B)
```

`\\` should not be in math mode, i.e., inside a pair of `$\\$`.

Comment: Then I got an error as follows:

Something's wrong-perhaps a missing \item. \end{frame}

Comment: I am able to compile your MWE with the change without any error (just a few warnings about font substitution).

Comment: I am still getting the same error :-(

Comment: Have you considered using an `array`?