# how to align an image using Tex/LaTex so it is above text

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, cv, resume

I am using the `res.cls` class to write my resume. And I thought it would be nice to put an image of myself just above the name.

However when I have used the `\includegraphics[scale =.09]{josh.JPG}` I have the option of it being aligned to the left, or centred.

Now given I want the image to be above my name in the resume, I thought `\centre` would do. But it is still to the left.

In Microsoft word I would just make the image free-transform and drag it where I want.

Is there a way to define how many pixels/cm etc an image is positioned from left or right?

**Question** I am not sure how to align the image directly over the Name in the resume document?

**Other Information**
Example --> Attached .gz file [tex, class file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8ezqnstr2969ha/tex-resume.tar.gz)
Tex Editor --> Linux Mint 16 TexMaker
Required Packages/Classes (res.cls)

**Update:** I have managed to centre the image, and would now be happy to get either the normal text John. D. Doe or the /name formatting from the resume class to sit directly under the image.

```
\documentclass[margin]{res} 
\textwidth=5.2in % increase textwidth to get smaller right margin

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document} 

\hfill \includegraphics[scale =.05]{josh2.jpg}\hspace*{\fill}\\
\begin{center}
{\bf John. Doe} \hspace*{\fill}
\end{center}

\name{John D. Doe\\}

\begin{resume}
\section{\underline{Objective}} 
        \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt
        \item To teach 
        \end{itemize}              

\section{Skills}  
{\bf Excel Automation:} 

\section{Work \\ History}
{\bf Business Analyst}  
          \begin{itemize}
          \item Dot Point
          \end{itemize}              

\end{resume} 
\end{document}
```

[image: headshot]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: why does stack overflow make a user sign up to each individual forum which is part of their network?

Comment: @yoshiserry: Your comment is a `meta` - question, and you posted actually three question in one, which should be avoided

Comment: About Q3: These are generally temporary  that are recreated each run. They don't have to be saved, but LaTeX needs them to save information between compilation runs. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files?lq=1 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7770/file-extensions-of-latex-related-files

Comment: About Q2: [Where do I place my own `.sty` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137) Finally: You didn't include the `.tex` file in that `.gz` file and we would need to see that. As ChrisS says, it's a lot easier if there is a proper example. And please add the code directly to your post, don't post a link to an archive somewhere else.

Comment: I have reworded my question to a single question - can it please be taken off hold?

Comment: I voted to reopen, but *please add the code of the `.tex` file as well*.

Comment: added the code - and I centred the image, but I need the centre and bold the text so it sits underneath the image.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you at least make sure that the code compiles without errors before adding it? I fixed a couple of typos and removed the `\caption`, so now it'll compile at least.

Comment: hi - I copied the text directly from TexMaker - it compiles.

Comment: Not without errors. You should have gotten one `environment centre undefined`, one `caption outside float` and one `Extra }`. But never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answers first question:

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}
\textwidth=5.2in % increase textwidth to get smaller right margin

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
%%\fbox is there just for demo
\name{\fbox{\includegraphics[scale =0.3]{photo}} \\ John D. Doe}

\begin{resume}
\section{\underline{Objective}}
        \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt
        \item To teach
        \end{itemize}

\section{Skills}
{\bfseries Excel Automation:}

\section{Work \\ History}
{\bfseries Business Analyst}
          \begin{itemize}
          \item Dot Point
          \end{itemize}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}
\textwidth=5.2in % increase textwidth to get smaller right margin

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
%%\fbox is there just for demo
\name{\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\fbox{\includegraphics[scale =0.3]{photo}}} \\ 
      \makebox[\linewidth][c]{\textbf{John D. Doe}}}

\begin{resume}
\section{\underline{Objective}}
        \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt
        \item To teach
        \end{itemize}

\section{Skills}
{\bfseries Excel Automation:}

\section{Work \\ History}
{\bfseries Business Analyst}
          \begin{itemize}
          \item Dot Point
          \end{itemize}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

[image]