# Auxiliary files - what does the file-extension '.fof' mean?

Tags: packages, external-files, auxiliary-files

Pertaining exactly to the topic of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7770/file-extensions-related-to-latex-etc) which asks about the various auxiliary files produced by tex and friends, I'd like to ask specifically about the `.fof` file extension. If the main file is `main.tex`, a `main.fof` is created.

I am asking here because I thought that this was a side-effect file that shall be automatically created and therefore ignored this in my VCS. However, after cloning the repository in another computer, `luatex` complained that this `fof` file was missing.

What is an `fof` file, and what information does it convey to the compiler?

Comment: as always a small test document would make your question more clear. `fof` isn't a file extension I recognise but a package that you are using could easily create files of that name.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Understood. Shall try to prune my code in a debug vcs branch and update the question here.

Comment: grep shows `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chkfloat/chkfloat.sty:% process the file .fof`

Comment: Aha. thank you very much. I am indeed using `chkfloat` to warn me when a float is placed too far from where it occurs in source.

Comment: @Troy please note reverted edit

Comment: @naphaneal  please note reverted edit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you suspect a package is generating a file name (or any other fixed string) you can search the tex input tree:

```
grep '\bfof\b' /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/*/*.sty
```

produces

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chkfloat/chkfloat.sty:% make \@caption write to a file .fof the information about final page, original page and float caption
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chkfloat/chkfloat.sty:  \addtocontents{fof}{\protect\chkfloat@{\thepage}{\chkfloat@page}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname: #2}}%
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chkfloat/chkfloat.sty:% process the file .fof
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chkfloat/chkfloat.sty:\@starttoc{fof}
```

which shows that this is float data used by the checking package.

(`grep` is a unix/linux tool but any search program would work here)

The regex keyword `\b` is used above to indicate word boundaries, which helps to narrow down the search output considerably to a smaller list that is easily parsable by the human eye.

Comment: This also suggests that OP should continue ignoring the .fof in the VCS, as chkfloat recreates the file as needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you very much. Much appreciate your help.

Comment: @Krishna your edit was rejected but it seemed fine to me so I added it by hand.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No issues. It wasn't a major thing anyway. But, thank you for the gesture.