# Should I version control the .fls file?

Tags: auxiliary-files

I have ommited the following files from my Latex repo.

```
*.aux
*.glo
*.idx
*.log
*.toc
*.ist
*.acn
*.acr
*.alg
*.bbl
*.blg
*.dvi
*.glg
*.gls
*.ilg
*.ind
*.lof
*.lot
*.maf
*.mtc
*.mtc1
*.out
```

I see my *Professor* submitted a `.fls` Latex file. Should this file be version controlled? I am trying to understand what this file refers to.

I see from another StackOverflow post ([File extensions related to LaTeX, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7770/file-extensions-related-to-latex-etc)) that:

`.fls - running latex with $ latex -recorder`

The question is whether this intermediate file `.fls` is auto-generated or this needs to be version controlled.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No**, the `.fls` file should not be version controlled because it is a build artefact.  That file is automatically generated when running LaTeX with the `-recorder` option and contains the full filesystem paths of all included files.  That also means that the contents of this file depend on the installation directory of your TeX distribution and is therefore likely to vary between different systems.

Comment: great description: _build artifact_  My word (s) of the day.

Comment: what is the usage of the `-recorder` command? Seems like it records the full filesystem path of all dependent files.

Comment: @Exploring Yes, that's what it does.  Build systems like `latexmk` use this to get a list of files that have to be monitored for changes to trigger a rebuild.

Comment: @DDuck That's common terminology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(software_development)