# Additional [auxiliary] files in LaTeX

Tags: auxiliary-files

I'm working with `LaTeX`. When I run the code, several files appear, which I don't know how to avoid. I erase these files, but when I run the code again, they reappear, as shown in picture (1).

I have the file `accounts`. The code is the last file in blue, the other files are files which contain informations like the picture (information and files which I don't find useful and I don't want to see in my folder) (2). How can I avoid it?

Picture (1)
[image]

Picture (2)
[image]

Comment: don't worry about them, and don't delete them they are needed. We have an answer listing what they all are I'll see if I can find it...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7770/file-extensions-related-to-latex-etc

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files

Comment: change your (windows?) settings so that is always shows file extensions, that makes the list much more readable.  And do you really have a period at the end of the file name??