# Compile extremely slow on VSCode

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I am using TeXLive 2023 with VSCode on Windows 10. Sometimes everything works fine, but troubles appear recently. Sometimes the compilation of files becomes extremely slow. Through the latexmk command, one can see that the compilation progress of the file is stuck on a file named bk10.clo. The only way to fix it is to uninstall the TexLive and reinstall it.

When it happened, I tried to compile a file with only 100 pages, which usually took 14 to 15 seconds to compile, and it actually took more than 2 minutes.

```
'pdflatex': time = 64.00
'makeindex main.idx': time = 0.33
'pdflatex': time = 62.36
Processing time = 127.48
Number of rules run = 3
```

After that I tried to compile an empty document with nothing but the title, which also took almost 2 minutes.

```
Latexmk: All targets () are up-to-date
'pdflatex': time = 56.80
'makeindex main.idx': time = 0.35
'pdflatex': time = 56.38
Processing time = 114.15
Number of rules run = 3
```

I really wonder what happened, and any help would be sincerely grateful!

---

A MWE is updated here:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=Source Han Sans CN Medium, ItalicFont=STKaiti]{Source Han Serif SC}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
    This is a test.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. A [*clo*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424669/297560) file usually contains definitions of a class option. Therefore, it would be really helpful if you could provide a MWE with some Info's about the class you're using etc.

Comment: do you have some security applications like a virus scanner which can slow down file access? Or is your texlive or your document in some unusual location (like a network drive)?

Comment: @lukeflo I am running on `ctexbook` class and using a package written by myself changing nothing but the default font by `\setmainfont` and `\setCJKmainfont`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, nothing but the Windows Defender. Actually the problem usually happens after leaving VSCode open and doing nothing for a while. It has reoccurred 3 or 4 times, but leaving it for a while does not always cause the problem.