# Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files

Tags: auxiliary-files

If I create just a basic `hello.tex` file an compile it using

```
pdflatex hello.tex
```

The `pdflatex` program is creating a plethora of file which is a little annoying. Currently it writes all those files about which I really don't care:

```
hello.aux, hello.log, hello.nav, hello.out, hello.snm, hello.toc
```

Is there a way to tell `pdflatex` to only write `hello.pdf` if the build is successful ? If not, can I specify the output directory of those files ? Maybe I could just write them in `/tmp`.

Comment: Sometimes you need those extra files. For example, aux keeps information about crossreferences and the like. They won't work unless latex can read that information from the aux file.

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2977/215) and [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7265/215)

Comment: Try using [Gummi](http://gummi.midnightcoding.org/). You'll have just the .tex file and the .pdf file. If you check out the screenshots, the "Error Output" will let you look at the log. It just doesn't leave a file behind to clutter things up. Gummi is best for small documents since it is constantly compiling to give you an almost immediate view of what you're creating.

Comment: May be you can try with arara: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87818/11232

Comment: FWIW, ConTeXt stores **all** the auxiliary information in a single file `filename.tuc`. So overall, only two extra files are written: `filename.tuc` and `filename.log`. If you want, you can compile the document using `context --purge filename.tex` which will delete the `.tuc` and `.log` files at the end of the run.

Comment: @Seamus "Sometimes you need those extra files." - Is it correct that the only drawback of deleting them is that LaTeX will require multiple passes on the next run? In such a case, it doesn't look as a serious problem: you just need to wait a few seconds more. Or there are other drawbacks? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is not the production of extra files - the problem is that THEY ARE PUT IN THE SAME FOLDER. Which is crazily annoying! Why can't latex just cleanly produce a folder "aux" in which all the clutter goes? And then reuse them from there? That would also have worked in 1978 when Latex was created...

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You might not care about these files, but `pdflatex` does quite a bit. These files hold information collected during the first run(s) and are needed to build the final PDF with correct ToC, references, PDF bookmarks, etc.

Your can delete these files afterwards, e.g. manually or using a front-end tool like `latexmk` (`-c` option). However, future compilations of the PDF would then need again several compiler runs.

You can define an output directory for *all* files using the `-output-directory` command line argument of `pdflatex`. After compilation you can then move the PDF in the current directory.

With MiKTeX, you can [specify a directory in which all the auxiliary files are put](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texfeatures.html#auxdirectory) (but not the PDF output) by using the `-aux-directory` command line argument. You can even combine `-output-directory` and `-aux-directory`.

Comment: _Why_ does LaTeX do this? Why doesn't it do the multiple runs in the background, keeping toc, references, bookmarks, etc. in memory instead of cluttering the filesystem?

Comment: @JonathanBaldwin TeX (upon which LaTeX is built) was written in 1978, before the PC era. It was designed to work in resource constrained environments, and therefore uses explicit multiple passes instead of keeping stuff in memory (and then breaking everything like word does).

Comment: Texmaker has an option called "Use a "build" subdirectory for output files" that will put all extra files in a folder called build automatically.

Comment: @MartinScharrer How do you automate the moving of the output pdf to a separate directory? Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Why is the MiKTeX behaviour of putting all aux-files into a separate folder not standard for the usual pdflatex-command? This would be so much cleaner!

Answer (score 64):

In addition to Martin's answer, I thought it might be useful to explain *why* LaTeX creates all these extra files. Let's take the example of the `.aux` file.

Let's say you have a `\label` in your document and a reference to it somewhere above where the label occurs. When pdflatex reads your `.tex` file, it reads the `\ref` first. Now, it doesn't know what to do with this ref: it hasn't yet encountered what it's referring to. Now when pdflatex reaches the label, it makes a note of what the label is referring to. By "makes a note" I mean it writes something to the `.aux` file that says roughly "when you encounter references to this, this is what is meant".

Then, on a second pdflatex run, when it reaches the reference, it looks in the `.aux` file and it knows what it is supposed to refer to and can substitute in the relevant text.

Auxiliary files are used for lots of other similar things (like tables of contents, lists of figures and so on). They are annoying, but deleting them after each run would break things. A lot.

Comment: I don't mean to raise a flamewar here, but maybe it's more fair to say that the `.aux` file is a kludge which is due to the current implementation of TeX. When I compile a C program, the compiler doesn't write a file with the memory offsets assigned to every variable, so it isn't clear why TeX should do something similar. Simply, it's an artifact from the past.

Comment: Actually, the C compiler does create such file, it's the object file.  Without knowing where the variables are, the linker would have pretty hard time linking everything together. If you run `make clean`, it usually remove these files for you, which is similar what you with do with tools like `latexmk`.  You are right that in most cases with TeX, this could be resolved instead by TeX itself making multiple passes through the file, storing the data in memory.  I believe I have seen someone trying to do something like that, but I don't really see why.

Comment: The C compiler creates the `.o` file *only if it is given an explicit command-line switch to do it*. Otherwise it keeps all in memory and spits out only the executable file. Moreover, when you modify only a portion of your program, typically most `.o` files are unchanged, so they are effectively useful as a "compilation cache" to reduce work. In contrast, typically, when you add a paragraph at the end of a `.tex` file the references change and you have to compile twice, so there is no saving. Tell me, how many other languages do you know where you normally have to compile your file *twice*?

Comment: You can use the `.aux` files as cache too, if you use for example `\includeonly`.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni While a C compiler can compile in a single pass (iff you don't want fancy optimizations), more modern languages can not be compiled in a single pass (e.g. Java or C#). In addition, only toy programs get compiled by passing all source files directly to the compiler. I can agree with you though that in this day and age there is little reason for TeX and LaTeX not to perform those passes by themselves.

Answer (score 31):

You already got lots of very good answers explaining why `pdflatex` needs all those auxiliary files. However you might still feel frustrated about having to live with all those files polluting a directory where (I'm guessing) you would like to keep all your LaTeX documents and their corresponding `.pdf` outputs.

> The best solution is to keep **one directory for each document** you have.

You can keep, for example, a main `Documents` folder and then individual `Paper1`, `Paper2`, ... folders; each with their own `main.tex` file. Then you can happily let LaTeX store whatever auxiliary files it wants in their respective folders. The difference is that now, for you, there is a clear structure of where your documents are.

Comment: pdflatex also has a CLI option for -aux-directory=dir, so you could simply have all your aux files and such. I remember seeing an easy way to make an alias to do this with just the pdflatex command, but I can't find it

Comment: @MercurialMadnessMan: The version of pdflatex I have under Debian Squeeze does not include an `-aux-directory` option. I think that is a MiKTeX option.

Comment: I am the boss of my computer. If I don't want my computer to make these files, it should not make these files. I understand that in the 80-ies it was wasteful to recompute everything. Today, my computer can compile my 1-2 page much faster than all the time I lose from auxiliary file mess that has been created.

Answer (score 29):

TeX writes the `.log` file.  It contains more information about processing the job than what is shown on the console.  It's very useful for debugging.

LaTeX writes the `.aux` and `.toc` files.  They are used for managing cross-references and table-of-contents information.  Since TeX's organism digests the input document from beginning to end, once per job, there's no other way to have a part of the document change based on later content.

The `beamer` class writes `.snm` and `.nav` files.  The `.snm` file is to assist you with including images of slides into an article version of the document.  The `.nav` file assists in creating navigation bars on slides.  Beamer is not apparently set up to suppress writing those files if they are not needed (i.e., if you do not need the functionality they enable).

The `hyperref` package writes the `.out` file to assist in creating bookmarks in the pdf file.  Sometimes this isn't needed; I looked at the last few jobs I had which used hyperref and the `.out` files are empty.  Again, this doesn't seem suppressable.

You can write the auxiliary files to a temporary directory.  Then you'll have to instruct TeX to look in that temporary directory.  Also you will have to make sure that the included auxiliary files are the right ones, not ones placed in the temporary directory by another process.

I think it's best to learn to live with these files.  If you don't want them after you're "done" with writing the document, just delete them.

Comment: If everyone thought according to your last paragraph, we wouldn't even have the printing press let alone computers and LaTeX. Rejecting the status quo is the first step of progress.

Comment: @JonathanBaldwin: Not all stati quo are created equal.  IMO the work needed to force LaTeX to not use auxiliary files will not lead to inventions on the level of the printing press.

Answer (score 20):

This is quite an old post with many good answers but, surprisingly, none of them mention `\nofiles`. There are times when you create documents with:

- no cross references (with `\ref` and `\label`)
- no citations (with `\cite`)
- no table of contents.

In these cases you don't want latex to create the long list of files mentioned above and you can tell it not to using `\nofiles`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\nofiles
\begin{document}
  Hello world
\end{document}
```

If you are running (pdf)latex "by hand" then the only files created will be the `.log` file and the `.dvi` (or `.pdf` file). If you are using something ike synctex then there will be a few more files for controlling the automatic compilation.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this workaround as a rough guide because I am not sure whether you are a Windows user.

### Step 1: create a batch file

```
rem batch.bat takes a input name without extension.
echo off

rem remove the previous PDF output to avoid confusion
rem when compilation fails.
del %1.pdf

pdflatex %1
pdflatex %1
rem list other programs such as
rem invoking bibtex, etc.

del %1.log
del %1.aux
del %1.nav
del %1.out
del %1.toc

rem other operations such as deleting or
rem renaming files.
```

Save it in a dedicated, safe folder such that reformatting hard disk will not lose it.

### Step 2: set the PATH

[image]

### Step 3: Configure TeXnicCenter

[image]

[image]

Comment: Two compiler passes may not be enough. In fact, theoretically there may be any number of LaTeX passes needed.

Comment: @Andrey: Of course. The batch above must be adapted to suit our need.

Answer (score 7):

Solution for **Emacs** with **AucTeX**, just run

```
M-x TeX-clean
```

This does not get rid of any temporary directories that are created, just files

Comment: Or just run `C-c C-c Clean`. Note that `C-c C-c Clean All` deletes also DVI or PDF file.

Answer (score 6):

I have the (Mac) application [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) watching my Articles folder and subfolders, with rules that delete all these auxiliary files after a certain interval since they were last modified. Usually it's two days or so. It cleans up files for papers I'm not currently working on.

Addressing the concerns about deletion raised above, if such files are needed in the future they can be created anew. Though this will require multiple runs, latexmk automatically runs the tex engine the necessary number of times, so they will be created.

Comment: Never new about Hazel - that's great!

Answer (score 5):

For those like-minded as me, and running linux:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

echo -n > .hidden
for i in *.out; do echo "$i" >> .hidden; done
for i in *.log; do echo "$i" >> .hidden; done
for i in *.aux; do echo "$i" >> .hidden; done
for i in *.bbl; do echo "$i" >> .hidden; done
for i in *.blg; do echo "$i" >> .hidden; done
for i in *.dvi; do echo "$i" >> .hidden; done
for i in *.toc; do echo "$i" >> .hidden; done
for i in *.synctex.gz; do echo "$i" >> .hidden; done
```

Put this bash script in your path, to do that put this line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:∼/scripts
```

into your `∼/.bashrc` file
(in this example ~/scripts is the folder containing the bash script above), this can be at the end of that file. Maybe you also have to run this file from the terminal, but this will ensure you can run this script anywhere, wherever you're keeping it.

Now you run this script in the terminal, while being in the directory needing cleaning. That means that if the script is named tex.clean, you'd browse to the folder needing cleaning in terminal, enter

```
tex.clean
```

in the terminal, and browse to the file in the graphical file browser, and it should be clean :)

All the file with endings mentioned in the script will be written to that directory's `.hidden` file. This means they will be hidden, but still usable :).

In nautilus (at least in fedora distributions) <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> will show or hide hidden files.

P.S. I tried to have this as detailed as I could so people new to bash and command line like me could use this. I hope I succeeded :).

Comment: You can avoid repetition of code by writing `for i in *.{out,log,aux,bbl,blg,dvi,toc,synctex.gz}`.

Comment: I didn't know that writing file names to a file called `.hidden` will hide them like all other files that start with `.`.  In which unices is that supported? (not Mac OS as far as I can tell)

Comment: It's not unix, only nautilus file manager (and possibly others, most certainly its forks nemo and caja) supports hiding via `.hidden`. If you browse that directory via `ls` you'll continue to see those files. Still, it's a fairly good solution to remove bothering files if you are a nautilus user.

Comment: This has nothing to do with file managers. In Linux (Unix) any file (or directory) starting with a dot is always a hidden file even in a terminal (ls  *cannot* show them) .  What a file manager make is un-hide that files by default (mc) of after a switch  shortcut as Ctrl-H

Comment: Of course, `ls -a` or `ls .*` can show hidden files of current directory, but not `ls` alone.

Answer (score 4):

Though this is an older question, I want to contribute something that might help people who love clean workspaces. I created a shell script that deletes all junk files at once. It will work on Mac and Linux; with some adjustments Windows should be possible too. Download the file "cleanlatexjunk.sh" from my repository and follow the instructions:

https://github.com/cgraumann/LatexUtils

1. Open *Preferences/Build* in TexStudio
2. Select *Advanced options* at the bottom
3. Add a new user command with the name `cleanjunk`
4. As the command, enter:

   `"/PATH/TO/SCRIPT/cleanlatexjunk.sh" -fp ?me ?a)`

   and change */PATH/TO/SCRIPT/* accordingly
5. In the meta-command for *Build & View* add `| txs:///cleanjunk` at the end

**Important**: As described by people before, the "junk" files are actually needed. Therefore you should also adjust your build workflow to do multiple compiles in a row. This assures that all TOCs and links are rendered correctly. *After* two or three compile runs, you can safely use my script as described.

Now every build & view execution should result in a clean workspace :-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
# write a makefile and remove all of the unwanted files after compilation.   
# change your folder structure as you see fit. 
# Folder structure
DOCDIR = doc/
TEXDIR = doc/tex/ 

# The compiler and the -output-directory flag
TCC = pdflatex
TEXFLAGS = -output-directory 

documentation: 
        $(TCC) $(TEXFLAGS) $(DOCDIR) $(TEXDIR)filename1.tex 
        $(TCC) $(TEXFLAGS) $(DOCDIR) $(TEXDIR)filename2.tex 
        $(TCC) $(TEXFLAGS) $(DOCDIR) $(TEXDIR)filename3.tex 
        rm -f $(DOCDIR)*.log 
        rm -f $(DOCDIR)*.aux            
        rm -f $(DOCDIR)*.toc 
        rm -f *.pdf
        rm -f *.aux 
        rm -f *.toc 
        rm -f *.log 

# Though if using this method you have to be careful with the image paths in  
# your tex source file. They're taken from the makefile directory.

# To use the file type >> make documentation << in a terminal 

# You can also do it like this

documentation: 
        $(TCC) $(TEXFLAGS) $(DOCDIR) $(TEXDIR)filename1.tex 
        $(TCC) $(TEXFLAGS) $(DOCDIR) $(TEXDIR)filename2.tex 
        $(TCC) $(TEXFLAGS) $(DOCDIR) $(TEXDIR)filename3.tex 

clean: 
        rm -f $(DOCDIR)*.log 
        rm -f $(DOCDIR)*.aux            
        rm -f $(DOCDIR)*.toc 
        rm -f *.pdf
        rm -f *.aux 
        rm -f *.toc 
        rm -f *.log 

# now >> make clean documentation << outputs with no crappy files
# and >> make documentation << outputs with the crappy files
# and >> make clean << cleans all the crappy files.
```

Answer (score 2):

For Mac OS X 18.* users (I'm using Mountain Lion) the `.hidden` file list does not appear to work any more for Finder. An alternative to the previous script would be

```bsh
for i in *.{out,log,aux,toc,bbl,dvi,blg,synctex.gz};
    do chflags hidden $i;
done
```

which also works in some flavors of Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Going back to why so many extra files (and why the C compiler doesn’t – apparently – do this): C is a language designed for single-pass compilation. Names must be defined before used. LaTeX isn’t. In a world with tight memory, the way to handle this is to use two passes, storing information needed for the second pass on the way through.

In today’s world with big memories, this is not entirely necessary. A LaTeX compiler could in principle store everything needed in internal tables and go back and patch in information as it became available.

If you really want to manage this properly, you need to work out how to use a makefile (or other similar build manager) to decide automatically when a second run is needed (some cases are obvious, like when you change your bibliography, others less so). Read [this](http://www.bouncingchairs.net/oss/latex.html) if you want to find out about Makefiles and LaTeX in detail.

Comment: "C is a language designed for single-pass compilation." False. C uses multiple passes (preprocessing, compiling, maybe some optimizing, linking, maybe more optimizing) and a C compiler may even choose to dump 5 million files into pwd that are useless after the passes are finished. Most compilers don't unless you tell them to.

Comment: The only thing that would be needed is that pdflatex puts all aux-files in a separate folder. That would have worked also in a memory-constrained environment and would be clean. Instead they put everything in the same folder cluttering stuff up. That is the problem.

Comment: Preprocessing isn’t really part of the compile. You can actually leave it out if you don’t need it. No one would call linking a compile stage. Optimizing isn’t a language requirement.

Comment: As it happens, the first compilers did use more than one pass: https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/primevalC.html – but the second pass was code generation, for reasons of small memory rather than a semantic requirement to read the source twice.

Answer (score 2):

**As of February 2022, there is now a simple solution to this question!** To quote from `latexmk`'s [changelog](http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8//latexmk/versions.html) for v4.73:

> Provide emulation of -aux-directory, so that it can be used with implementation other than MiKTeX

This means that if you build your document with `latexmk`, all you have to pass is a location where the auxiliary files will be dumped. For example, to build your `hello.tex`, run:

```
latexmk -pdf -emulate-aux-dir -aux-directory=\tmp hello.tex
```

---

You'll need the an updated version of `latexmk`—my Latex distribution, MacTex-2021 doesn't have it. You can check which version you have by running `latexmk --version`. It needs to be v4.73 or later. I was able to upgrade by running:

```
tlmgr update latexmk
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **OpTeX** instead **LateX**. OpTeX creates its `.ref` file (and only this, no more) only if it is explicitly needed. I.e. if there are forward references, request to creating table of contents etc. But if you process

```
Hello world
\bye
```

by OpTeX, then only `hello.pdf` and `hello.log` are created.

Answer (score 1):

There's still another option, you can merge the Clean button and the close button in TexMaker so when you close all the auxiliary files are deleted. This way you don't have to remember to Clean all the time yet you can still use the auxiliary files as long as you don't close.

This can be done downloading the sourcecode. The important file is texmaker.cpp and the processes are CleanAll and fileClose

Comment: This is a feature in Configure Texmaker > Commands > Launch the "Clean" tool when exiting Texmaker

Answer (score 1):

Texmaker includes an option to "use a build directory for output files" which kind of does the trick.

If you enable this setting Texmaker creates a 'build' folder in the same directory as the document .tex file.  It automatically cleans the old output and outputs into the build folder instead.

The setting works well but isn't perfect.  For example I've found that after adding a new citation to the document Bibtex complained when it couldn't find the .aux file.  I had to copy the aux file back out of the build folder to compile the document.  I'm not sure if there's a way to fix that yet.

Answer (score 1):

These files are needed but yes, there's no need to have them at the same path. Use this bash script to avoid cluttering of the folder containing your .tex file:

```
# plcl: pdflatex clean
infile=`readlink -f "$1"`
inpath=`dirname "$infile"`
tmpath="/tmp/pdflatex`echo "$inpath" | sed -e 's/\//-/g'`"

mkdir "$tmpath"
pdflatex -output-directory "$tmpath" "$1"
mv "$tmpath"/*pdf "$inpath"
```

This requires bash and sed.

Answer (score 1):

The LaTeX build wrapper [ltx2any](https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any) may be a solution. This does not prevent the creation of all the auxiliary files, but places them in another directory, which you can specify

```
ltx2any -t path_where_you_want_the_auxiliary_files_to_go filename.tex
```

This path can very well be a `tmp` folder.

For more options, see `ltx2any --help`.

Answer (score -2):

Just do it: It's dirty but useful.

```
cd /usr/bin && mv pdflatex __backup_real_pdflatex
vim pdflatex
```

```
#!/bin/bash

fname="$1"
/usr/bin/__backup_real_pdflatex $@ && rm -f "$fname."{log,nav,out,aux,toc,snm}
exit $?
```

WARNING: The script above is not tested even once!!

Comment: So this will delete all the files after a single compile. How do you manage dealing with cross-references that need the `.aux`, or your Table of Contents that needs the `.toc`?

Comment: @Werner So it can only handle the simple cases. That's why I say it's "dirty but useful".