# Having pdflatex clean up after itself in WinEdt?

Tags: auxiliary-files, winedt, cleanup

How do I get `pdflatex` (via WinEdt) to remove all the extra output files (e.g., `.lof`, `.blg`, etc.) after compiling my `.tex`/`.bib`/`.etc` to a `.pdf`?

If there is a solution, I suspect it will come via "*Options*" -> "*Execution Mode*". I'm just not finding anything though :(

I was told by someone that `pdflatex` won't do this and that I would need to create a Makefile. Is that true?

Comment: Related question: [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Winedt has the "Erase output files" tool (on the "Tools" menu).

*However*, you don't want to remove the auxiliary files after each run of pdflatex because you need those files for subsequent runs.

If you are using miktex, then you can run `texify` with the `-c` option to automate running `pdflatex` sufficiently many times, and `bibtex` etc and then remove the aux files. In miktex you can access this by going to "Execution Modes...", choosing "PDFTeXify" and adding `-c` to the "Switches" box.

Comment: Wonderful! This worked perfectly. Thank you Lev.

Comment: I'll also add that I found online documentation for what you're talking about at <http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texifying.html>. I put in --clean as the switch rather than -c. It'll be easier to remember what was going on if I ever come back to this in the future :)

Comment: I do have a follow-up question that I may have to ask in an entirely new post: how could I have determined the answer to this question without using help forums? E.g., via the Linux shell I could have found this documentation with a simple "man texify" (I'm assuming, I don't have Latex installed on my Linux box to verify). BUT, there seems to be no equivalent from MS DOS command line. I've tried "help texify" and "texify \?" to no avail.

Comment: @brianjd: `texdoc texify`. `texify --help` gives a summary.

Comment: @brianj: If Lev's answer worked for you, you should accept it (and up vote it, if you haven't done so).

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe that's is possible. Anyway, if I'm not mistaken, there's an option in MiKTeX's `pdflatex` where you can set a temporary folder to store your `aux` files (This option is not available in TeX Live's `pdflatex`).

```
 pdflatex -aux-directory=DIR ...
```

Files won't be deleted, but at least they won't be in the same folder as your main `.tex` file.

When in Windows, I usually create a `clean.cmd` file which will remove those files for me:

```
del *.bak
del *.aux
del *.bbl
del *.blg
del *.log
```

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: `pdflatex -output-directory` seems to be the right command.

Comment: @asrtqwftrast: Actually, `-output-directory` would relocate the pdf file as well, and I don't think that's desired here.