# An MS command line equivalent to Linux's "man" for help on Latex files?

Tags: documentation

Is there an MS DOS command line equivalent to Linux's "man" for finding help on Latex files?

e.g., if I were running Latex on Linux I could do:

```
man texify
```

to discover a file like [this](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texify.html), from which I could learn, say, that `--clean` as a parameter will clean up auxiliary files after compilation. Instead, I find myself bothering the good people of Stack Exchange with questions like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11765/having-pdflatex-clean-up-after-itself-in-winedt). I've tried

```
help texify
```

and

```
texify /?
```

to no avail.

Basically, I'd just like to be self-sufficient, working with the man-files rather than running to the forums with every question of mine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`texdoc X` will generally work, where `X` is a package (`texdoc xcolor`) or a documentclass (`texdoc revtex4-1`) or a command (`texdoc texify`) will generally work. Also some others: eg `texdoc miktex` for the miktex manual, `texdoc source2e` for the complete documented latex2e sources or `texdoc letterfaq` for the complete TeX FAQ.

Comment: If the same command line switches work as on the Linux/MacOS side of things, you can also do `texdoc -s <name>` to find all the documentation that contains <name> in its filename.  This sometimes works better if your first attempt brings up something unexpected.

Comment: It seems `texdoc` in TeX Live is more powerful than MiKTeX.

Comment: I should add: using your response as a starting point, I was able to find [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4358/where-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-possible-texdocs) that `mthelp` is to MikTeX (my distribution) as  `texdoc` is TexLive.

Comment: FYI, I posted a follow-up question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/latex-equivalent-to-rs-help-foo) regarding how to use this utility (or something similar) for finding documentation on particular latex macros (e.g., `\section`)

Answer (score 2):

if you have installed a [tcl/tk](http://www.tcl.tk/) version, then you can run `texdoctk`