# Keyword-Based Documentation Help

Tags: documentation

When refering to shell commands and system calls, `man` provides a consistent, systematic, offline reference. The python interpreter's `help` command does the same for python. Does *tex have an equivalent?

Comment: texlive has a texdoc command that fills this function (although the results are not as consistence as man, they are better typeset:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: MikTeX also has a version/variant (I'm not sure which) of `texdoc`.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440588 .

Comment: Related/Possible Duplicate of [LaTeX equivalent to R's `help foo`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/latex-equivalent-to-rs-help-foo) or [An MS command line equivalent to Linux's “man” for help on Latex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11780/an-ms-command-line-equivalent-to-linuxs-man-for-help-on-latex-files). Also have a look at [Which books can I read via texdoc?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107720/15717)