# How can I change where preview latex stores its generated files?

Tags: auctex

I love preview-latex but it litters my directories with its temporary files. I've scanned the documentation of previewlatex, auctex, and the latex preview package but can't find a variable that lets me customize where it generates files :(

If I could shove that stuff in a build/ directory that'd be great. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: There is a variable called `preview-temp-dirs` with the docstring "List of top level temporary directories in use from preview. Any directory not in this list will be cleared out by preview on first use."

Comment: I don't use auctex, but this question might be interesting: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files

Comment: refer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files

Comment: I know about pdflatex's output redirecting, but that doesn't solve the problem. There is no exposed interface (that I know of) to preview-latex's use of pdflatex, so I would have to monkey patch auctex in a number of places. I was hoping there was a better way that I missed :)

Comment: I made some progress on this but ended up giving up due to the amount of effort. If you grep for .prv in the preview-latex source, there are some functions that manipulate the cache filenames. Override these in your .emacs and it should be OK but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

[Comment by OP converted to answer]

I know about pdfLaTeX's output redirecting, but that doesn't solve the problem. There is no exposed interface (that I know of) to preview-latex's use of pdfLaTeX, so I would have to monkey patch AUCTeX in a number of places. I was hoping there was a better way that I missed :) I made some progress on this but ended up giving up due to the amount of effort. If you grep for `.prv` in the preview-latex source, there are some functions that manipulate the cache filenames. Override these in your `.emacs` and it should be OK but YMMV