# AucTeX preview-latex temporary files

Tags: emacs, auctex, preview

How can I tell `preview-latex` to store all temporary files (especially the folder `_region_.prv` which contains the preview images) in `/tmp` and **not** in the folder of my actual `.tex` file, when I'm using it with AucTeX in emacs?

I checked the documentation and also looked in the customize-group of preview and auctex for a variable that allows me to select the directory for temporary files but without success. I know, that this question was already asked [3 years ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43486/how-can-i-change-where-preview-latex-stores-its-generated-files) but without any real solution as far as I can tell. Maybe now 3 years later there is a solution for this?

In the case, that this really would not be possible, is there a way to delete all this preview related files (*including* the `_region_.prv` folder) on exiting the `.tex` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible to do it easily with AUCTeX and I think it's not a good idea to modify a package so I provide a solution to clear the folder.

You can definie a function `clear-preview`:

```
(defun clear-preview () (shell-command "rm -rf *.prv preview.fmt"))
```

If there is other file created by the preview function you can add them also.

Comment: @BenjaminSchiel you're welcome. Do other file are created or not? If it's the case I must modify the answer to have a proper clean function

Comment: Yes sometimes there is a preview.fmt file created for the previews. It would be good to delete it too.

Comment: @BenjaminSchiel answer update 

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer, it's now (as of auctex-11.89, probably earlier) possible to set the prefix for the AUCTeX region files (`_region_.tex` etc.) by customising `TeX-region`, away from the default `_region_`. (This is relevant for the `_region_.prv` folder.) For example, one can set the variable to `.auctex_region_`, at least causing the generated files to be "hidden" files. Note, however, that under most normal configurations, LaTeX cannot touch hidden "dot" files, due to security reasons (for some details [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198629/is-it-possible-to-compile-hidden-files)), so with the above setting of the variable, `TeX-command-region` and the like won't work; `preview-latex`, though will still work normally.

Unfortunately, naively setting `TeX-region` to a string containing a slash, to force the files to be placed in a subdirectory, does not work — the `_region_.tex` file will be located in the subdirectory, as desired, but the latex child process will output its files into the project root directory instead and AUCTeX won't find them.

Additionally, the value of the prefix for the `prv_` files appears to be hard-coded in `preview.el` in the function `preview-dump-file-name`. Obviously, one could override the function or advise it, but that seems less elegant and future-proof.