# Tell tex distribution to avoid residual temporary files

Tags: compiling, auxiliary-files, logging

When I compile a tex document, the compilation process usually leaves some temporary files, like .aux and .log.

I have got a small document that can be compiled in just one single run - can I tell the compiler to remove all the remnant temporary files?

Comment: See [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11123/23160).

Comment: if your document really required only one pass to compile, you can avoid producing some of those files by inserting `\nofiles` just after the `\documentclass` line.