# Files created when saving new document

Tags: auxiliary-files

When I make a new .tex document, three other files are created as well, .pdf, .aux and .synctex. I want the .pdf file, but are the other two necessary, can I delete them? Can I tell latex to not create .aux and .synctex files?

Comment: Possibly also not a duplicate of that specific question, this is more of a question of relevance rather than how to delete them...

Comment: `\nofiles` in the preamble will prevent generation of files, but it's not recommended, since it will prevent the generation of the correct labelling/referencing information as well the ToC related content

Comment: If you don't consider that to be a duplicate, here is the duplicate for the other half of the question: [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11123)

Comment: @PaulGessler That's the right one.

Answer (score 2):

`\nofiles` in the preamble prevents the generation of the helper files. However, this will lead to the fact that

- `.aux`
- `.toc`
- `.idx`
- `.lof`
- `.lot`
- `.gls`
- `.bbl`

and all job-dependent files can't be written, so changes made after `\nofiles` is applied won't be updated, leading most probably to wrong references and page numbers. Those files are generated by the (La)TeX compilation step, in conjunction with other tools such as `makeindex` or `biber`.

There is no way in TeX itself to delete files (as far as I know)

Comment: [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201324)

Comment: @PaulGessler: Thanks, did not search for that ;-)