# Table of contents causes compilation timeout

Tags: table-of-contents, compiling

Writing my master's thesis and changed how I define the sections from

```
\section*{\centering sectionname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{sectionname}
```

to simply

```
section{sectionname}
```

This was done after feedback that I should number my sections.

The problem is that whenever I try to compile my document I get an error stating that the compilation timed out (using sharelatex.com free user, so the timeout occurs after 60 seconds).
The thing is that if I just comment out `\tableofcontents` the whole document compiles in about 20 seconds without any problems. The only other changes I did to the document which I can think of was to change the text in some of my sections, which shouldn't cause this problem at all. The only section commands I use now are `\section{}`, `\subsection{}` and `\subsubsection{}`.
I even tried to comment out a majority of my document and only compile a small part of it including `\tableofcontents` but I still get the same timeout message. Heads up is that I'm still very new to LaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You have changed to `\section{section name}` (with a backslash), right? Have you considered deleting all auxiliary files and compiling again?

Comment: Deleting the auxiliary files and then recompiling solved the problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is due to the fact that `LaTeX` 'flounders' a bit<sup>*</sup> between the old entries in the table of content that do not exist anymore (`\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{sectionname}`), and the new ones that have the same name (generated by the `\section{}` macros).

The solution is thus to **delete the auxiliary files** to have a fresh start (actually, just the `.aux` one should be enough): at first compiling, `LaTeX` will identify the new keys but won't create the ToC since it has no previous informations about them. A second run will generate the ToC based on the actual `\section{}`s.

<sub>*I know there is a rational reason behind it, but I'm not skilled enough to know it `(-;`</sub>

Comment: More explanations on how does the `.aux` file works can be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11130/64454)