# Global setting to save additional files to subdirectory of tex file with TeXStudio

Tags: texstudio

I have a bunch od auxiliary files in the directory of tex file after compiling each tex document.
I simply want to generate a build folder in this directory to store all the auxiliary files.
I run through a lot of posts.

For example in the following:

[Global setting to prevent latex from generating additional files with TeXStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329367/global-setting-to-prevent-latex-from-generating-additional-files-with-texstudio)

it is said that `pdflatex -aux-directory=aux %.tex` can solve this.

But the question is **where** **exactly I** **need to type this command in TeXstudio**?
When I append this:
[image]

I receive an error.

All I need is to clean this mess:

[image]

Comment: I am using Latex for 15 years and NEVER use any of this auxiliary files. I always **manually** delete them after each compilation. I am tired of doing this always after each compilation...

Comment: But why delete the auxiliary files after each compilation? It is enough to do this at the very end of the work. The deletion does not have to be done manually. Use the Tools / Clean Auxiliary Files menu for this.

Comment: Use `arara`, it will `clean` extra files for you if you specify their extension i.e. `log`, `toc`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 99% of my Latex work is exams/test preparation for the students. Each exam is only at one side. This time I decided to prepare lecture notes using  tcolorbox.

Comment: @hair-splitter where exactly is Clean Auxiliary Files - I couldn.t find this in tools...