# TexMaker generates additional files

Tags: compiling, texmaker

I'm currently testing TexMaker and whenever I compile my .tex file these are the files that appear in the folder:

[image]

I'd like to have only .tex and .pdf files in my folder. Are the extra files necessary?

Also, are they exclusive to TexMaker or would I have the same problem in another editor?

Comment: I think, you can delete all the files except *.tex and *.pdf files. There files are generated during every build, irrespective of the editor. In some editor, there is some shortcut to delete the un-necessary files.

Comment: @Amit that's not really good advice! If you delete `.aux` then cross references will not work, if you delete `.log` it's hard to debug errors, if you delete `synctex.gz` association between the viewer and the source file is lost.

Comment: note that texmaker is not related to this issue, that is the editor used to create the source but all the other files are made by the tex system not by the editor you are using.

Comment: A more relevant question on this site is http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11123/15925 .  Does that answer your enquiry?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes, that's pretty much it. Should I delete this question or can I merge them somehow?

Comment: We will close it as a duplicate.