# Clean-up temporary files after PDF is generated

Tags: auctex, auxiliary-files, aquamacs, cleanup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting external/auxiliary files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24785/deleting-external-auxiliary-files)

Is anyone aware of a way of how to cleanup temporary files generated by `pdflatex` during the generation of the PDF file? I came across the pdflatex parameter `-aux-directory=` but I cannot find where to set it. I also came across some sort of macro called `LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes`, but neither am I sure how I can execute it manually or even better automatically after the compilation.

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24785/deleting-external-auxiliary-files and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/need-aux-file-in-seprate-folder and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/bundle-tex-output-in-a-directory

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with `pdflatex` but it is with [`latexmk`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) by using the option `-c` as in

```
latexmk -c foo.tex
```

See [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files/11125#11125) for details.

---

Why use `latemk` instead of `pdflatex`? Because it makes compilation easier. You just have to issue `latexmk` once and it runs `pdflatex`, `bibtex` or `biber` and `makeindex` as many times as it takes for the document to be fully compiled. It has several other features you might like too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! They look very promising ;) 

In fact I use now the following solution, based on latexmk. http://jon.smajda.com/2008/03/08/latexmk/

Comment: One reason for not using latexmk is that it cannot determine image sizes automatically as pdflatex can do. You have to call it `latexmk -pdf foo.tex`