# Using glossaries in Texlipse

Tags: glossaries, texlipse

Is there a way of adding a glossary using the glossaries package in Texlipse?

```
%%% GLOSSARIES
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{A}{name=area,description={Area}}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\section{Section Header}
Text Text Text

\end{document}
```

(I have installed Perl as I am on a windows system (as per the documentation) but that doesn't seem to  have changed anything...unless I missed some key part!)

Comment: You have to run the `makeglossaries` script after the LaTeX run and run LaTeX again. This can be conveniently done via `latexmk` or simply by a shell command.

Answer (score 13):

I spent some time fiddling with this, and finally made it work. The instructions should be platform-independent, but for reference, this is on `Eclipse 3.7.2/Texlipse 1.5.0/Win7 x64/MikTeX 2.9`. I opted out of using the `makeglossaries` script since Perl is not usually found on Windows systems, and I had some issues with the script when the directories of the input and output files were not the same. `makeindex` should work well enough.

---

1. Specify a place for the temporary/auxiliary files created by `glossaries`

   - In Eclipse, go to `Window->Preferences->Texlipse->Builder Settings->Latex Temp Files`
   - Add the following `glossaries`-specific extensions: `.ist`, `.gls`, `.glg` and `.glo`

   This will move the temp files to the `tmp` directory after each build so they don't get in the way. This is kind of optional and you can make do without it, but it keeps your source directory clean.
2. Create a new `make glossaries` external tool configuration:

   - Go to `Run->External Tools->External Tools Configurations...` and create a new configuration. Name it any way you want.
   - In "Location" field, use the path to the `makeindex` command.
   - In "Working directory", use `${project_loc}\tmp`. This is project-independent, so you won't have to update it for each new project.
   - In "Arguments", use the following:

     `-q -s ${project_name}.ist -t ${project_name}.glg -o ${project_name}.gls ${project_name}.glo`

   Add any relevant `makeindex` customizations as necessary. I used the `-q` flag to suppress printing the log messages to the console in Eclipse, but you can take it out for debugging purposes.
3. Run the glossaries after every build:

   - Open your project and go to `Project->Properties->Builders`
   - Choose `Import...` and select the builder we just made.
   - Go to `Edit...` for the builder and then go to `Build Options`.
   - Check `Launch in background`, `During manual builds` and `During auto builds`.
   - Uncheck `After a "Clean"` and `During a "Clean"`.
   - Leave the rest as they are.

   If your main `.tex` file is named differently from your project, then replace all references to `${project_name}` in the "Arguments" section appropriately (do this for the imported builder, not for the external tool, naturally). Don't bother creating a new variables, this will only apply to your current project anyway so just hard-code them and call it a day.

You might have to build twice for the references to appear, since the tool is only executed after each build, and you'd need another one for them to appear. This is similar to the way you do this manually -- you'd need another call to `{pdf}latex` after you have executed `makeindex`.

Comment: There's a possibility that I might have missed a step since I tried a lot of things until I made it work. If so, please let me know and I'll edit in what's missing.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a comment about running multiple times the pdflatex command.

Comment: Did you find a way to make this building automatic while maintaining auto-refresh of the PDF using PDF4Eclipse?

Comment: Worked great for me but ${project_loc}\tmp as a working directory did not work for me. I'm using Ubuntu. Had to change it by clicking on "Browse workplace". Is there a better way?

Comment: This worked for me after much fiddling. Future readers, keep in mind [*an extremely toxic bug with absolute paths*](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17190/89787) when you are trying to create a small variation of this builder rule; the gist is to only ever use relative paths. This becomes especially relevant when you want to work with the `tmp`-folder while the `idx` file is in the project folder.

Comment: @mtanti On Linux systems, use a forward slash instead of a backslash. This might also apply to Apple systems, I don't remember ATM.

Comment: It looks like TeXlipse has a setup to invoke `makeindex` (just like `biblatex`) out of the box, however it won't work if `glossaries` is set up to use `xindy` (and neither will this answer, most probably).

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution using makeglossaries and keeping the PDF synced with PDF4Eclipse.

This solution is based on [this post](https://forum.finf.uni-hannover.de/index.php?page=Thread&postID=58845#post58845)

1. Install Perl
2. Make sure you have the makeglossaries.exe in your your tex distribution bin folder
3. Make sure that you can call makeglossaries from the command line directly.

   ```
   $> makeglossaries    
   makeglossaries: Need exactly one file argument.   
   Use `makeglossaries --help' for help.
   ```
4. Next create a .bat file (gloss.bat) in your project folder in Eclipse and put the following content

   ```
   @echo off 
   cd "%~dp1"
   set texSource=%~n1
   pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials "%texSource%.tex"
   makeglossaries "%texSource%"
   pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials "%texSource%.tex"
   pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials "%texSource%.tex"
   pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials "%texSource%.tex"
   ```
5. Now in Eclipse, under `Window --> Preferences --> Texlipse --> Builder Settings` you should edit the Pdflatex command to the following:

   ```
   Program File: <pathtoprojectfolder>\gloss.bat
   Arguments: %input
   ```
6. Add the following extensions to the list of temporary files in `Window-->Preferences-->Texlipse-->Builder Settings-->Latex Temp Files`:

   - .ist, .glo, .gls, .glg, .acn, .acr, .alg

Comment: I upped the answer because it worked. However, this method makes incremental builds very slow (especially when there were no changes to the glossaries.