# What is the best way for a list of nomenclature?

Tags: nomenclature

My problem with the `nomencl` package is that I have to call `\nomenclature` manually every time I use a new symbol.
For example the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace,ifthen}

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Notations}
\renewcommand*{\pagedeclaration}[1]{\dotfill\hyperpage{#1}}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{\item[\textbf{Roman Symbols}]}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{\item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{P}}{\item[\textbf{Superscripts}]}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{B}}{\item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{Symbols}]}{%
      }}}}}}

\makenomenclature

\newcommand{\symbI}{\ensuremath{F}\xspace}
\newcommand{\symbII}{\ensuremath{M}\xspace}
\newcommand{\symbIII}{\ensuremath{\alpha}\xspace}
\newcommand{\symbIV}{\ensuremath{U}\xspace}

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature[1.5cm]

\section*{Math section}

\begin{equation}
   \symbI = \symbII \symbIII
\end{equation}
\nomenclature[rsymbI ]{\symbI}{some explanation for F}
\nomenclature[rsymbII ]{\symbII}{some explanation for M}
\nomenclature[gsymbIII ]{\symbIII}{some explanation for \alpha}

\end{document}
```

would produce

[image]

Is there any way, let say, that one defines all the symbols once and only those that used in the text appear in the list of nomenclature? Something similar to citation maybe.

For example to have the following way in order to produce the above nomenclature list?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}

\anicecommand{\symbI}{Roman sympbol}{\ensuremath{F}\xspace}{some explanation for $F$}
\anicecommand{\symbII}{Roman sympbol}{\ensuremath{M}\xspace}{some explanation for $M$}
\anicecommand{\symbIII}{Greek sympbol}{\ensuremath{\alpha}\xspace}{some explanation for $\alpha$}
\anicecommand{\symbIV}{Roman sympbol}{\ensuremath{U}\xspace}{some explanation for $U$}

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature[1.5cm]

\section*{Math section}

\begin{equation}
   \symbI = \symbII \symbIII
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know a way to do that with the `nomencl` package, but it is easily feasible with `glossaries`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\acronymname}{List of Notations}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{0.1\hsize}p{0.8\hsize}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
     \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\bfseries\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\\[5pt]}%
}

\newcommand*{\Rgroupname}{Roman Symbols}
\newcommand*{\Ggroupname}{Greek Symbols}

\newcommand*{\myacro}[4][sort=s]{%
  \newacronym[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #2\endcsname{\acrshort{#2}}%
}

\myacro[sort=ra]{symbI}{\ensuremath{F}\xspace}{some explanation for $F$}
\myacro[sort=rb]{symbII}{\ensuremath{M}\xspace}{some explanation for $M$}
\myacro[sort=ga]{symbIII}{\ensuremath{\alpha}\xspace}{some explanation for $\alpha$}
\myacro[sort=rc]{symbIV}{\ensuremath{U}\xspace}{some explanation for $u$}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossary[style=mystyle,type=\acronymtype]

\section*{Math section}

\begin{equation}
   \symbI = \symbII \symbIII
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I've defined a new glossary style `mystyle` which simulates the output of `nomencl` and used it in `\printglossary`.

Notice the new commands

```
\newcommand*{\Rgroupname}{Roman Symbols}
\newcommand*{\Ggroupname}{Greek Symbols}
```

used to define the subheadings. Probably you will have to define

```
\newcommand*{\Pgroupname}{Superscripts}
\newcommand*{\Bgroupname}{Subscripts} 
\newcommand*{\Sgroupname}{Symbols}
```

Also note the definition of symbols, for example:

```
\myacro[sort=ra]{symbI}{\ensuremath{F}\xspace}{some explanation for $F$}
```

`sort=ra` is needed to insert the symbol in the "Roman Symbols" list (the `r`) and to sort it as the first one in the list (the `a`).

When

Comment: Thanks! This works fine. For those who use `Texlipse` like me need to do some extra stuff as well explained [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45416/using-glossaries-in-texlipse)

Comment: @A.GH You're welcome. Happy it helped.

Comment: Brilliant, but can this also work for variables with arguments? Something like `\corr{a}{b}`?