# How to check if the argument of a macro has an underscore?

Tags: macros, glossaries, underscore

I'm using the glossary definition from [What is the best way for a list of nomenclature?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164933/what-is-the-best-way-for-a-list-of-nomenclature). I need a macro that checks if the argument contains underscore symbol ("_"). I defined `myfun` but the argument inside the macro is `\acrshort(symbI)` instead of `F_a`. How can I solve this issue? Thank you for advance!!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\acronymname}{List of Notations}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{0.1\hsize}p{0.8\hsize}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
     \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\bfseries\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\\[5pt]}%
}

\newcommand*{\Rgroupname}{Roman Symbols}
\newcommand*{\Ggroupname}{Greek Symbols}

\newcommand*{\myacro}[4][sort=s]{%
  \newacronym[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #2\endcsname{\acrshort{#2}}%
}

\myacro[sort=ra]{symbI}{\ensuremath{F_a}\xspace}{some explanation for $F$}
\myacro[sort=rb]{symbII}{\ensuremath{M}\xspace}{some explanation for $M$}
\myacro[sort=ga]{symbIII}{\ensuremath{\alpha}\xspace}{some explanation for $\alpha$}
\myacro[sort=rc]{symbIV}{\ensuremath{U}\xspace}{some explanation for $u$}

\makeglossaries


\usepackage{listofitems}

\newcommand{\myfun}[1]{
    \setsepchar{_}
    \readlist\mymat{#1}
    \ifnum\mymatlen>1
    \textbf{Do something when the argument has \_}\\
    \else
    \textbf{Do something when the argument does not have \_}\\
    \fi
    \textbf{the argument is: } \showitems*\mymat
}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[style=mystyle,type=\acronymtype]

\section*{Math section}

\begin{equation}
   \symbI = \symbII \symbIII
\end{equation}


$ \myfun{\symbI} $

\end{document}
```

The code returns:

[image]

and I expected to obtain:

[image]

## (edit) Second code from Steven B. Segletes' code

If I use a macro to define a new acronym the code doesn't works. Now, I'm using `\mysubscripta` in `\simbV` to add `_a` in the definition of the acronym.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\acronymname}{List of Notations}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{0.1\hsize}p{0.8\hsize}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
     \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\bfseries\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\\[5pt]}%
}

\newcommand*{\Rgroupname}{Roman Symbols}
\newcommand*{\Ggroupname}{Greek Symbols}

\newcommand*{\myacro}[4][sort=s]{%
  \newacronym[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #2\endcsname{\acrshort{#2}}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #2def\endcsname{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\mysubscripta}[1]{#1_a}

\myacro[sort=ra]{symbI}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{F_a}}\xspace}{some explanation for $F$}
\myacro[sort=rb]{symbII}{\ensuremath{M_d^e}\xspace}{some explanation for $M$}
\myacro[sort=ga]{symbIII}{\ensuremath{\alpha}\xspace}{some explanation for $\alpha$}
\myacro[sort=rc]{symbIV}{\ensuremath{U}\xspace}{some explanation for $u$}
\myacro[sort=rc]{symbV}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{\mysubscripta{F}}}\xspace}{some explanation for $F$}

\makeglossaries


\newcommand{\myfun}[1]{
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\findus
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname#1def\endcsname}%
    {has \_}{does not have \_}
}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\findus[3]{%
  \gdef\usfound{F}%
  \tokcycle{\ifx_##1\gdef\usfound{T}\fi}{\processtoks{##1}}{}{}{#1}%
  \tctestifcon{\if T\usfound}{#2}{#3}}
\begin{document}

\printglossary[style=mystyle,type=\acronymtype]

\section*{Math section}

\begin{equation}
   \symbI = \symbII \symbIII
\end{equation}

symbI $ \myfun{symbI} $

symbII $ \myfun{symbII} $

symbV $ \myfun{symbV} $

\end{document}
```

The main objective of solving this issue is to define a macro to add a subscript and superscript to an acronym and to avoid the double subscript/superscript error. For example, I want to do `\myfun{\symbI}` and it will retunrs `F_{ab}^{c}` where `\symbI` is `F_a` or `\myfun{symbII}` and it will returns `M_{db}^{ec}` where `\simbII` is `M_d^e`.

Comment: The replacement text of `\symbI` contains no underscore: it expands to `\acrshort{symbI}` and this, in turn is not expandable; the underscore will appear when *printing* the result, way down what can be controlled with macro expansion. What would be the need for such a check?

Comment: You could put the argument into a savebox and compare it to \dp\strutbox.

Comment: I would like to know if the argument has an underscore to avoid double subscript. Depending on whether or not it has underscore, I will define the subscript one way or another. For example, I want to do `\myfun{\symbI}` to add a subscript, therefore, the macro should returns `{F_a}_{b}`

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
\myacro[sort=ra]{symbI}{\ensuremath{F_a}\xspace}{some explanation for $F$}
```

, then the *⟨control sequence⟩* `\symbI` will not deliver the tokens `\ensuremath{F_a}\xspace` but will deliver a call to `\acrshort` while `\acrshort` is not fully expandable. What does this mean? Expansion takes place in TeX's gullet. (Temporary) Assignments etc take place in TeX's stomach. Some tokens coming from expanding `\acroshort...` are intended to trigger (temporary) assignments or changes of fonts etc and therefore need to be processed by the stomach for subsequent tokens also coming from expanding `\acroshort...` being processed/further expanded correctly.
So you need a check which takes place in TeX's stomach while all checking and forking by means of expandable `\if.. ...\else ... \fi`-tokens and whatsoever intriguing macro-trickery can take place only at a prior stage, in TeX's gullet. Thus your request is sort of contradictory to the ways in which TeX works.

But the acronym-package internally defines a control sequence `\glo@symbI@short` which delivers the result of applying `\protected@edef` to the tokens `\ensuremath{F_a}\xspace`.

Thus you can get hold of the tokens passed to `\myacro` via

```
\csname glo@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\glsdetoklabel
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\@gobble\string⟨control sequence⟩}@short\endcsname
```

The underscore is nested in curly argument-braces of `\ensuremath`.

So you need a routine for detecting underscores that might be nested in curly braces.
In the example below I wrote my own routine `\CheckWhetherUnderscore` for detecting whether a sequence of tokens contains an underscore of category code 8(subscript).

In order to find out if the expansion of the acronym underlying `\SymbI` delivers an underscore you can apply  `\CheckWhetherUnderscore` to the result of expanding `\glo@symbI@short`.

But this does not deliver information whether the expansion of the acronym underlying `\SymbI` delivers control sequences which themselves expand to stuff with underscores.

Summa summarum:

You wish a check whereby `\myfun`'s argument contains `\SymbI` and/or whatsoever other stuff (which probably isn't fully expandable either) while `\SymbI` cannot be used as it is not fully expandable.

All I can do for you is provide a routine `\CheckWhetherUnderscore` for detecting whether a sequence of tokens contains an underscore of category code 8(subscript) and show how to apply it to the top-level-expansion of `\glo@symbI@short`.

Be aware: In case the top-level-expansion of `\glo@symbI@short` contains an underscore, the routine `\CheckWhetherUnderscore` detects the presence of that underscore no matter if that underscore would get gobbled/removed when further processing the tokens coming from expanding `\glo@symbI@short`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%%///////////////// Code of my own routine for defining checks ////////////////
%%////////////////////// for presence of token sequences //////////////////////
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo,
%%    \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange, \UD@removespace
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull, \UD@CheckWhetherBrace,
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens, \UD@ExtractFirstArg
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@removespace{}\UD@firstoftwo{\def\UD@removespace}{} {}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\z@\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\z@\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is a catcode-1-character
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has leading
%%                        catcode-1-token>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has no leading
%%                        catcode-1-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBrace[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
  \string#1.}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\z@\UD@firstoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\z@\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's leading tokens form a specific 
%% token-sequence that does neither contain explicit character tokens of 
%% category code 1 or 2 nor contain tokens of category code 6:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{<argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                              {<a <token sequence> without explicit 
%%                                character tokens of category code
%%                                1 or 2 and without tokens of
%%                                category code 6>}%
%%                              {<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case
%%                                <argument which is to be checked> has
%%                                <token sequence> as leading tokens>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case 
%%                                <argument which is to be checked>
%%                                does not have <token sequence> as
%%                                leading tokens>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[3]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\expandafter\z@\UD@secondoftwo}{%
    \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
    \UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens#3{\relax}#1#2}{}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
  {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\z@\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter}\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<token sequence>}%
%% Defines <internal token-check-macro> to snap everything 
%% until reaching <token sequence>-sequence and spit that out
%% nested in braces.
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner[2]{%
  \@ifdefinable#1{\long\def#1##1#2{{##1}}}%
}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@InternalExplicitSpaceCheckMacro}{ }%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Extract first inner undelimited argument:
%%
%%   \romannumeral\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{ABCDE\UD@SelDOm} yields  {A}
%%
%%   \romannumeral\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{{AB}CDE\UD@SelDOm} yields  {AB}
%%.............................................................................
\@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm{%
  \long\def\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1#2\UD@SelDOm{{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\z@#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1}}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% \DefineCheckForTokenSequence{<Macro for perfoming the check>}%
%%                             {<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                             {<token sequence>}%
%%
%% defines <internal token-check-macro> and <Macro for perfoming the check>.
%%
%% Syntax of <Macro for perfoming the check> is:
%%
%% <Macro for perfoming the check>{<tokens to check>}%
%%                                {<token in case <tokens to check> contains
%%                                 <token sequence> at least once>}%
%%                                {<token in case <tokens to check> does not
%%                                 contain <token sequence> >}%
%%
%% !!! <token sequence> must not contain explicit character tokens of catcode 1 or 2 !!!
%% !!! <token sequence> must not contain tokens of catcode 6 !!!
%% !!! <token sequence> must not be empty !!!
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\@ifdefinable\DefineCheckForTokenSequence{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\DefineCheckForTokenSequence[3]{%
    \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{#2}{#3}%
    \newcommand#1[1]{%
      \romannumeral\UD@CheckForTokenSequenceLoop{##1}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckForTokenSequenceLoop[3]{%
  % #1 - <tokens to check>
  % #2 - <internal token-check-macro>
  % #3 - <token sequence>
  % Do:
  %  \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{<internal token-check-macro>}{<token sequence>}%
  %  \romannumeral\UD@CheckForTokenSequenceLoop{<tokens to check>}%
  %                                            {<internal token-check-macro>}%
  %                                            {<token sequence>}%
  % 
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\expandafter\z@\UD@secondoftwo}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{#3}{#2}{%
      \expandafter\z@\UD@firstoftwo
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{#1}{%
        \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@CheckForTokenSequenceLoop
                     \romannumeral\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#1\UD@SelDOm}{#2}{#3}%
        {\UD@firstoftwo}%
        {\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\UD@secondoftwo}%
      }{%
        \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{ }{\UD@InternalExplicitSpaceCheckMacro}{%
          \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\UD@secondoftwo
        }{%
          \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\UD@secondoftwo
        }%
      }%
      {\expandafter\z@\UD@firstoftwo}%
      {%
       {\expandafter\UD@CheckForTokenSequenceLoop\expandafter{\UD@removespace#1}}%
       {\expandafter\UD@CheckForTokenSequenceLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}}%
        {#2}{#3}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother
%%=============================================================================
%%///////////// End of code of my own routine for defining checks /////////////
%%/////////////////////for presence of token sequences ////////////////////////

% Define a check for presence of `_` :

\DefineCheckForTokenSequence{\CheckWhetherUnderscore}{\InternalUnderscoreCheckMacro}{_}%

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\acronymname}{List of Notations}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{0.1\hsize}p{0.8\hsize}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
     \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\bfseries\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\\[5pt]}%
}

\newcommand*{\Rgroupname}{Roman Symbols}
\newcommand*{\Ggroupname}{Greek Symbols}

\newcommand*{\myacro}[4][sort=s]{%
  \newacronym[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #2\endcsname{\acrshort{#2}}%
}

\myacro[sort=ra]{symbI}{\ensuremath{F_a}\xspace}{some explanation for $F$}
\myacro[sort=rb]{symbII}{\ensuremath{M}\xspace}{some explanation for $M$}
\myacro[sort=ga]{symbIII}{\ensuremath{\alpha}\xspace}{some explanation for $\alpha$}
\myacro[sort=rc]{symbIV}{\ensuremath{U}\xspace}{some explanation for $u$}

\makeglossaries


\usepackage{listofitems}

\newcommand{\myfun}[1]{%%%
    \setsepchar{_}%%%
    \readlist\mymat{#1}%%%
    \ifnum\mymatlen>1 %%%
    \textbf{Do something when the argument has \_}\\
    \else
    \textbf{Do something when the argument does not have \_}\\
    \fi
    \textbf{the argument is: } {\hbox{\csname verbatim@font\endcsname\showitems*\mymat}}%%%
}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[style=mystyle,type=\acronymtype]

\section*{Math section}

\begin{equation}
   \symbI = \symbII \symbIII
\end{equation}


$ \myfun{\symbI} $

\parindent=0pt
\vfill\hrule\vfill

\verb|\CheckWhetherUnderscore{A BC#1{De{g}F}}{Underscore present}{Underscore not present}|:\\
\CheckWhetherUnderscore{A BC#1{De{g}F}}{Underscore present}{Underscore not present}

\vfill\hrule\vfill

\verb|\CheckWhetherUnderscore{A BC#1{De{g{_}}F}}{Underscore present}{Underscore not present}|:\\
\CheckWhetherUnderscore{A BC#1{De{g{_}}F}}{Underscore present}{Underscore not present}

\vfill\hrule\vfill

\verb|\CheckWhetherUnderscore{_}{Underscore present}{Underscore not present}|:\\
\CheckWhetherUnderscore{_}{Underscore present}{Underscore not present}

\vfill\hrule\vfill

\verb|\CheckWhetherUnderscore{ }{Underscore present}{Underscore not present}|:\\
\CheckWhetherUnderscore{ }{Underscore present}{Underscore not present}

\vfill\hrule\vfill

\verb|\CheckWhetherUnderscore{}{Underscore present}{Underscore not present}|:\\
\CheckWhetherUnderscore{}{Underscore present}{Underscore not present}

\vfill\hrule\vfill

\verb|\CheckWhetherUnderscore{A_B}{Underscore present}{Underscore not present}|:\\
\CheckWhetherUnderscore{A_B}{Underscore present}{Underscore not present}

\vfill\hrule\vfill

\makeatletter

\verb|\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\CheckWhetherUnderscore|\\
\verb|\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%|\\
\verb|  \csname glo@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\glsdetoklabel|\\
\verb|              \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%|\\
\verb|              \expandafter\@gobble\string\symbI}@short\endcsname|\\
\verb|}{Underscore present}{Underscore not present}|:\\
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\CheckWhetherUnderscore
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \csname glo@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\glsdetoklabel
              \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
              \expandafter\@gobble\string\symbI}@short\endcsname
}{Underscore present}{Underscore not present}

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I understand why my code does not work. Can you suggest me a method to define my glossary and a macro to add a subscript and superscript to an acronym? Like `\myfun{symbII}` and it will returns `M_{db}^{ec}` where `\simbII` is `M_d^e` and, also, it was defined using several acronyms.

Answer (score 0):

The macro `\findus` searches the unexpanded argument for a `_` and forks to `#2` or `#3` accordingly.  I have incorporated it into the OP's `\myfun`.

It works even if the `_` is embedded down in a group, as in the case for `\mathrm{F_a}`.

REEDITED to handle OP's additional case, in which the `_` was not explicit, but contained in a macro definition.  I this case, I adjusted the macro `\findus` to apply a `\protected@edef` to its argument, to expand as much as possible.  In this way it can find content that expands to `_`, in this case, `\mysubscripta`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\acronymname}{List of Notations}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{0.1\hsize}p{0.8\hsize}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
     \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\bfseries\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\\[5pt]}%
}

\newcommand*{\Rgroupname}{Roman Symbols}
\newcommand*{\Ggroupname}{Greek Symbols}

\newcommand*{\myacro}[4][sort=s]{%
  \newacronym[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #2\endcsname{\acrshort{#2}}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname #2def\endcsname{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\mysubscripta}[1]{#1_a}

\myacro[sort=ra]{symbI}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{F_a}}\xspace}{some explanation for $F$}
\myacro[sort=rb]{symbII}{\ensuremath{M}\xspace}{some explanation for $M$}
\myacro[sort=ga]{symbIII}{\ensuremath{\alpha}\xspace}{some explanation for $\alpha$}
\myacro[sort=rc]{symbIV}{\ensuremath{U}\xspace}{some explanation for $u$}
\myacro[sort=rc]{symbV}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{\mysubscripta{F}}}\xspace}{some explanation for $F$}

\makeglossaries


\usepackage{listofitems}

\newcommand{\myfun}[1]{
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\findus
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname#1def\endcsname}%
    {has \_}{does not have \_}
}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\findus[3]{%
  \protected@edef\tmp{#1}%
  \gdef\usfound{F}%
  \def\tmpA{\tokcycle{\tctestifx{_####1}{\gdef\usfound{T}}{}}
  {\processtoks{####1}}{}{}}%
  \expandafter\tmpA\expandafter{\tmp}%
  \tctestifcon{\if T\usfound}{#2}{#3}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\printglossary[style=mystyle,type=\acronymtype]

\section*{Math section}

\begin{equation}
   \symbI = \symbII \symbIII = \symbV
\end{equation}

symbI $ \myfun{symbI} $

symbII $ \myfun{symbII} $

symbV $ \myfun{symbV} $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How does this solve the problem in the question? The OP wants to know whether in the eventual expansion of `\acrshort{symbI}` there is an underscore.

Comment: I answered the direct question, how to determine if argument has an underscore.  I have edited to address that issue in the context of the OP's situation.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works for this example, but if I add a new acronym using a macro like the second code added in the OP, it doesn't work. Do you know what I need to modify from your answer?

Comment: The request in the question is about `\myfun{\symbI}` working out.You wrote code for `\myfun{symbI}` to work out. In the question it isn't said that `\myfun` is to work only with a single thing defined via `\myacro`. In `\myfun`'s argument there might be several things defined via `\myacro` with/without underscore and several things not defined via `\myacro` whose processing at some stage yields an underscore to be processed somewhere after TeX's gullet while in math-mode...One would probably need to  crank out `\csname A_B\endcsname` or `\input File_A.tex` or `\@gobble{_}` or `\iffalse _\fi`.

Comment: @Ruco I haved edited my answer. Basically, you must program the `\tokcycle` to look for not only explicit values of `_`, but for macros that will expand to `_`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I have reedited my answer to apply `\protected@edef` to the argument, which accomplishes much in revealing that which expands to a `_`.

Comment: @Ruco I have further simplified my answer, by doing a protected expansion to the argument, in search of `_`.