# Sorting logs into different folders

Tags: compiling, auxiliary-files, logging, workflow

When I run `xelatex` (or other compilers), I always end up with many log files in a single folder. This gets difficult to manage. I could create a script which moves them into various folders (e.g. one for glossary-related logs, one for bibliography-related logs), but then the compiler would not find them the next time they compile. Is there a simple way to tell `xelatex` to put the logs into specific folders?

Comment: `xelatex` creates only _one_ logfile. I suppose that you mean additional runs by `bibtex`/`biber` or similar or files like `.aux` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some directory related switches you can pass to `XeLaTeX`. Theses are:

- `--aux-directory=aux-directory`
- `--include-directory=include-directory`
- `--output-directory=output-directory`

These were taken from the [XeTeX manual on the MiKTeX homepage](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/xetex.html).
XeLaTeX will not create these directories, so they have to be created before compilation. On Windows, you cannot use `aux` as directory name.
You might also want to read this [related question regarding pdflatex & Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35052/placing-intermediate-and-output-files-in-another-folder).

Comment: I find that doesn't work for me (I have the 2009 TeX Live that come in Ubuntu).  The command `xelatex --aux-directory=aux fn` results in `fn.aux` appearing in the current dir, whether or not `aux` is an existing directory, and whether or not I enable write18.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Have you tried `--aux-directory=aux-directory` as well as `-aux-directory=aux-directory`?

Comment: Could you try a name other than aux for the folder? Not sure about Linux, but on Windows you cannot have folders named aux.

Comment: I'm not sure we are allowed to have this conversation, but no, changing to `-aux-directory=fred` or `--aux-directory=fred` or other nearby variants does nothing that I can see.  On the other hand, `--output-directory` get everything, including the `.pdf`.

Comment: The first two of these flags are specific to MikTeX and will _not_ work with TeXLive.