# copying the compiled pdf in a folder from within tex file

Tags: external-files, auxiliary-files

In order to keep clean the folder where my .tex file is, I have successfully adopted the strategy suggested in other posts (see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35052/placing-intermediate-and-output-files-in-another-folder)  or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24785/deleting-external-auxiliary-files)), setting `-output-directory=build` and `-aux-directory=build` and adding `./build` in the additional search paths for the log file and the pdf file in the build advanced options.

This works, though all the files (including the pdf) are now in the `build` subfolder, whereas I would  like to have the pdf in the same folder where the .tex file is.

To this aim, I created a simple batch file called `copy.bat` and put it in the same folder where the .tex file is. Its content is:

```
for /R "%cd%\build" %%f in (*.pdf) do copy "%%~f" ".\"
```

What it does is to copy all the pdf files from the build subfolder to the current folder. If run from terminal it works as expected.

Now, I would like to run the .bat file from within the tex file I am working on. I have changed the PdfLatex command option so that now it is:

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape -output-directory=build -aux-directory=build %.tex
```

I have then included `\immediate\write18{"./copy.bat"}` in my tex file, but I get an error when I try to compile (the pdf is corrupt). 
I really can't understand why. As a side question, would you use a different strategy to copy the pdf in the tex directory?

Comment: The pdf is not finished when you call your script.Why do you use `-output-directory` when you don't want to redirect the pdf?

Comment: Conversely, make a batch file that run pdflatex with options you need, and copy your pdf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer because without it I still have the synctex.gz file in the main folder. But I agree it's mostly because of my stubborness. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to wait until th pdf is finished?

Comment: How should this be possible? Use some tool like arara or latexmk or build tools of your editor if you want to do some clean up after the job.

Comment: do you really need synchronization? if yes don't `-output-directory=build` you'll lose it otherwise. if no you can try `pdflatex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape -aux-directory=build %.tex` and every thing is fine.

Comment: I think for it's just ok to set `aux-directory', though I would enjoy to be able to create such directory automatically from Texstudio.