# creating auxiliary files folder if it doesn't exist

Tags: texstudio, external-files, auxiliary-files

If it doesn't exist, I would like to automatically create the subfolder `./temp` where to put the auxiliary files with `-aux-directory=temp`.
Can this be done in Texstudio 2.10.2?

(see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273607/copying-the-compiled-pdf-in-a-folder-from-within-tex-file) and the links there to check how to change the directory of the auxiliary files and/or output).

#### EDIT:

The accepted answer works just fine in case there is no bibliography.
However, Texstudio returns error if a bibliografy in included (`Error: Could not start the command: sh -c "mkdir ...`).
Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Running `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option, with `\immediate\write18{mkdir -p ./temp}` as the first line of the document (if you're on a Unix system). But it seems much more complicated than just creating the folder when the document is first set up.

Comment: thanks, that's a good alternative, but I was trying to do everything from within Texstudio, if possible.

Comment: My advice is doing a feature request to the developers.

Comment: You could alter the command executed by TS couldn't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the command for `pdflatex` yourself to create a directory
if necessary. This would be something similar to

```
sh -c "mkdir -p temp & /usr/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=temp %.tex"
```

Details may vary depending on the operating system and on the TeX
distribution.

See also the corresponding [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/843/).

Comment: `/usr/texbin` is no longer correct for current Macs because `/usr` is no longer writeable.

Comment: @Tim Hoffman, thanks, it does exactly what I needed! (using Windows 7). For future reference, I create both the auxiliary files directory `temp` and the output directory `output` with `sh -c "mkdir -p temp output & pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=output -aux-directory=temp %.tex`

Comment: P.S.: the above command should be put in the `PdfLaTex` box in `Options > Configure Teststudio > Commands`. As usual, the directory relative path should be specified in `Configure Teststudio > Build` (clicking on advanced options box). In my case, `./temp` and `./output` under Log file and Pdf file, respectively.

Comment: @Tim Hoffman I updated the initial question to make it more general. Can you suggest a way to make your solution work in case a bibliography is added to the document?