# Bibtex does not find .aux files of chapters included with \include in output folder

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, pdftex, texstudio

I recently split my thesis in several files each containing one chapter which is included with `\include` in the main Latex-file.
I call `pdflatex` with `-output-directory=output` to keep the source directory clean.

The problem is that `bibtex` does not find the axuliary files for the included subfiles. I call it with `bibtex ./output/%.aux` and it finds the main.aux but not any of the sub-aux.files such as chapter1.aux, chapter2.aux, etc.

The problem seems to be that the path to the output folder is not included in the main.aux. When I change the path there manually for example from `\@input{1_intro.aux}` to `\@input{output/1_intro.aux}` everything compiles fine.

Is there any way to make `pdflatex` write the proper paths into the main.aux?

I am using TexStudio on a Linux machine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Comment: The next one making his/her own life more difficult by using `-output-directory`.

Comment: Is it not recommended? I had about 60 files of wildly mixed types in the same directory and `-output-directory` seemed to be the prefered solution for that.

Comment: I never use it. And your question shows why: In LaTeX outputfiles are often also *input*files, and sorting out all the tools when you move some of your input files somewhere else can be complicated.  Search the site for related questions.

Comment: I changed it back to cluttering the main folder but I'd still be thankful for any advice concerning the problem described above. I don't get why Latex doesn't use a special directory for temporary/auxiliary files anyway. They are almost never useful for the user and quite frankly annoy me a lot...

Comment: @heuamoebe You may want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313228/36296

Comment: Check out the question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12686/128181 I know it's a bit late, but this may help others.

Answer (score 1):

It's late, I leave this for future generations...

Do you need to use `\include` or may you use `\input`? If you use the latter, a unique .aux file is created (instead of one for each .tex file), and you get away with calling `bibtex` from the main directory like you already do:`bibtex ./output/%.aux`

(not my idea, credits to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518934)