# BibTex does not compile when Output file "build" is used

Tags: bibtex, citing

I'm new to LaTex. I'm using TexMaker and Tex Live 2017, with BibTex 0.99d. Sadly i run this on Windows 10. 
So the Problem is, i use the output file "build" for a better overview on the data-files.[image]But when i compile with those [image: fast compiling settings] settings, i get only question marks in brackets [?] as citation and this massage:

`Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX) The top-level auxiliary file: build/main.aux I couldn't open auxiliary file titel.aux ---line 23 of file build/main.aux : \@input{titel.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command The style file: abbrv.bst Database file #1: masterbib.bib Warning--there's a number but no volume in "literature9999" (There was 1 error message)

Process exited with error(s)`

When i do not use the "build" output file everything works fine.
As you can see i already modified the "Bib(la)tex" command to "bibtex build/%". I found this in [BibTeX error in TexMaker {I couldn't open file name `test_bb.aux'}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85075/bibtex-error-in-texmaker-i-couldnt-open-file-name-test-bb-aux). But it does not work for me.

Glad for every help.

Greetings Vince

Comment: I'm not new to latex and I *never* use such build folders. Why fight with unusual file locations?

Comment: using a separate folder for the axillary files will just make your life way more complicate. In case you use the build option to keep your directory "clean", have a look at tools like https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any instead.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313228/36296

Comment: In contrast, many of us do find it convenient to have a separate build directory to avoid polluting the source directory.  Latex, pdflatex, etc have an -output-directory option to support this.  The primary problem is that bibtex alone doesn't.

Comment: In the original post, the commands configured in TeXMaker appear wrong:  1. pdflatex and lualatex would normally have an -output-directory to use a build directory.  2. The normal bibtex command does not work properly with a build directory.  I suggest an easy solution might be to use latexmk, which is already programmed to take care of properly using a build directory; then also you don't have to worry about the separate commands.  (But you'd have to work out if there any complications in using TeXMaker with latexmk configured to use a build directory.)

Comment: Thanks to you three for your answers.
@UlrikeFischer Like John Collins said: 'many of us do find it convenient to have a separate build directory to avoid polluting the source directory'. I like to see my .txt files separated from all output files. And it makes it easier for me to copy them to work on ubuntu, too.

Comment: @samcarter I think i'll try out ltx2any. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @JohnCollins Well thats odd. Why does TeXMaker then have the "build" file option? :D Maybe i'll check latexmk out. But first i have to get some progress on my work. ;)