# TeXstudio Auxiliary Files Build Folder

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio, auxiliary-files, directory

I'm having issues setting up an auxiliary file folder. I have followed the instructions from several different threads but I'm still coming up with an error. Below is the commands I have set up (where "build" is the folder I want to save to):

[image]

This is the window that keeps popping up: 
[image]

I know this has been asked several times before but none of the answers seem to solve the problem!

Comment: Do yourself a favour and don't use a build folder. It causes more trouble than it solves. Depending on why you want to use one, there are other solutions.

Comment: I just dislike the mess they make of the folder. What other solutions are there?

Comment: In this case my suggestion is ltx2any, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313228/36296

Comment: I use texstudio (latest release) together with a build folder (the directory is called `tmp` here). Note_1: I told texstudio to use latexmk for compilation, using this parameters: `latexmk -outdir=tmp -silent -lualatex -latexoption="-synctex=1 %%O %%S" %` Note_2: Add your build directory (here: ./tmp) to the additional search path section in texstudio's configuration tab called "Build", so that texstudio can find the log and the resulting PDF file. That should do the trick. Oh Note_3: I use biber, using these params: `biber.exe --output_directory tmp %`

Answer (score 2):

for me the following worked:

go to Options --> Configure --> Commands:

1- PdfLaTeX: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=build %.tex

2- BibTeX: bibtex.exe build/% -include-directory=build

but my only problem is that i have to create the 'build' folder myself.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the very same error ("Could not restart Recompile:PdfLaTeX:...").
The reasons in my case were twofold:

1. The error occured if I had \i in my bibtex file, e.g.

   author    = {C{'{e}}sar A Rodr{'{\i}}guez-Rosario ...

Removing the \i to i solved the problem

2. I used the package hyperref wrong:
   \usepackage[backref]{hyperref}

Correct usage (order is important)

```
\usepackage[hyperref=true, backref=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

I removed it, and the problem was solved