# latexmk - "(Pdf)Latex failed to generate the expected log file" when using -auxdir flag

Tags: compiling, latexmk

I'm using `latexmk` Version 4.41. Calling `latexmk -pdf document_template.tex` compiles fine without any errors. However when I attempt to output all the aux files into a folder `tmp` with the following command:

`latexmk -auxdir=./tmp/ -pdf document_template.tex`

I get the following error:

```
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'tmp/document_template.log'
Latexmk: Did not finish processing file 'document_template.tex':
   (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'tmp/document_template.log'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
```

And only the `.aux` and the `.fdb_latexmk` file will be in the `.\tmp` folder, whereas the rest of the aux files are in the same folder as the `.tex` document. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and don't use another directory for the aux files - this causes way more problems then it solves. However if you really insist on doing it, use a tool like `ltx2any` which deals with most of the resulting problems.

Comment: @samcarter Can you please elaborate on what kind of problems this would cause?

Comment: This will cause problems when using a bibliography, index and many other things.

Comment: see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313228/36296 for a demonstration of possible problems

Comment: @spurra What TeX system are you using?  With TeXLive, the -auxdir option is not supported, since the underlying TeX engines don't support it.  If you try using it, pdflatex will itself give an error message, and latexmk will give the message you showed. Only the -outdir option is supported when you use TeXLive.

Answer (score 3):

I've got exactly the same problem. After exploring a bit I've found the following.

### Diagnostic

First, I'm working on MacOSX using MacTex as the Latex compiler. The `latexmk` documentation says the following:

> *-auxdir=FOO* Sets the directory for auxiliary output files of (pdf)latex (.aux, .log etc). This achieves its effect by the -aux-directory option of (pdf)latex, which currently is only implemented on the MiKTeX version of (pdf)latex.
>   (Taken from: https://man.cx/latexmk)

I'm not using MikTex so I´ve suspected this was part of the problem. (more info here: [Latex distributions. What are their main differences?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239199/latex-distributions-what-are-their-main-differences))

### Solution

Add the option `outdir` and point it to the same directory as `auxdir`. In your case would be:

`latexmk -auxdir=./tmp/ -outdir=./tmp/ -pdf document_template.tex`

This will put all the derivative files into `tmp`

### Check if you need auxiliary folders

If you use the \include{} command inside your latex document you may need to create a directory inside the `tmp`directory.
More info here: ([latexmk -outdir with \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206695/latexmk-outdir-with-include))