# Placing xelatex.exe Intermediate and Output Files in Another Folder

Tags: xetex, texstudio, output

I want to save the output from a xelatex run into a different folder.
I found the following explanation [Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35052/placing-intermediate-and-output-files-in-another-folder)

I have the fontspec package loaded in my preamble.  in Texstuido i changed 
Menu > Options > Configure TeXstudio > Commands [Tab] > xelatex

to

xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=output %.tex

Texstudio is compiling my document with errors, but fontspec indicates that it is not actually xelatex what is used for it?

The error reads :

> Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex" The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX. You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex". For immediate help type H .

If i change the settings back to xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex everything works fine it seems.
I compile via the menu entry Tools- command - Xelatex in either case.

Comment: (1) why don't you post some code and (2) cite the error. We do not have access to your system, so we need more information

Comment: Hi the error reads : `Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex" The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX. You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex". For immediate help type H <return>.` If i change the settings back to  `xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` everything works fine it seems

Comment: Update your question with that information. It clearly says you are not compiling using xelatex, so that it probably your problem. Exactly what do you do to compile.

Comment: i edited the initial post